# document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src= vs <script src=

Tags: javascript

Apart from allowing you insert js variables into a script tag when written like `document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src=` what are the pros/cons of this vs a normal `<script src=>` tag?

I'm mainly asking with regard to speed but interested in the whole story.

Thanks
Denis

Comment: I don't see any question

Comment: Stackoverflow does this: `document.write('<s'+'cript lang' + 'uage="jav' + 'ascript" src="http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?`

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: @Paul. not really as I get why we split it. 

What I'm wondering is if I have a choice to split it and use a js variable or not split it and use a serverside variable, apart from reduced code bloat do I get anything inway of a speed increase or otherwise by going the server option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is to gain non blocking javascript loading.

For this i suggest looking at Steve Souders posts about the subject.
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/

The LABjs library solves this in a pretty nifty way.
http://labjs.com/

Also it seems newer browsers are beginning to load things parallel by default
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/07/browser-script-loading-roundup/

Answer (score 9):

There is no need for `'<scr'+'ipt'`.
There is need for `'<\/scr'+'ipt>'`. Because HTML interpreter has no need to understand Javascript, so it will treat everything between `<script>...</script>` as the text, and won't care `var a='</script>';` is a string literal Javascript, it will consider it the closing tag for `<script>` and regard the remainder of the script text as plain (erroneous) HTML.

edit: corrected per David's suggestion

Comment: And that's wrong too. It should be: `"<\/script>"` since HTML parsers (at least ones which implement HTML correctly, i.e. not most web browsers) will treat `</` as an end tag.

Comment: `"<\/script>"` not `"<\/scr" + "ipt>"`. The latter is pointless, inefficient, hard to read bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Other than those? There aren't any.

(Incidentally, splitting a script tag in a JS string into a pair of concatenated strings is pointless bloat)