# Concatenation of 'scr'+'ipt' in javascript bookmarklet code

Tags: javascript

Given [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474185/112196) on the same topic I feel I understand the apparent justifications for concatenating the `<script>` tag as `'<scr'+'ipt..'` in a javascript string, even if this itself is [misguided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236429/112196).

However, looking at the code for the [Instapaper bookmarklet](http://www.instapaper.com/extras) I see `d.createElement('scr' + 'ipt')`. The relevant part of the code (beautified) is at the end of the question.

Even if this (anti-)pattern is to avoid the HTML parser balking at the markup after the occurrence of the closing `<script>` tag within a javascript string, I can see even less justification for doing it here given the concatenated text does not even represent a `<script>` tag.

In this case, is this done for some other reason?

```
javascript: function iprl5() {
    var d = document,
        z = d.createElement('scr' + 'ipt'),  //???
        b = d.body,
        l = d.location;
```

Comment: Someone was sleeping at that time.

Comment: I think it is just a dogmatic application of the pattern without an understanding of why it's done. ``var test = document.createElement('script');`` doesn't barf on me (and I wouldn't expect it to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is silly to escape `"<script>"` as it will *not* be parsed as tag inside a script block* and it is *even sillier* to treat `"script"` as special. It's not. It lacks either a `<` or `</`, without which it will never be parsed as a tag -- in any context. Thus `f("script")` and `f("scr"+"ipt")` have identical semantics.

Technically in HTML, *all* `</` in a script block need to be guarded against, but in practice browsers only care about `</script>`. Because of this, `"<"+"/script>"` is what I recommend, but that applies only to closing tags. That is, `"<script>"` (or `"script"` as the case may be) is perfectly valid inside a script block.

Happy coding.

---

*By a compliant *HTML parser*: however, hand-rolled (regex) parsing may explode in terrible ways. The XML/XHTML rules are different, but then the `<` needs to be encoded for those to be well-formed *anyway* ... perhaps some obscurities with CDATA? In any case, it is irrelevant to HTML.

Also, the linked answers *do not* argue for `"<scr"+"ipt.."` (or subsets like `"scr"+"ipt"`): instead, they argue for guarding against the *closing* script-tag construct, which begins with `</`, that is not even present in the code in the post...

Comment: I got in the habit of breaking my `'<scr'+'ipt'` tags up because my editor would sometimes get confused, and fail at syntax highlighting the rest of the file.  It's not a need, but might explain why some people do it.

Comment: @Umbrella A very valid point; [sometimes sadly,] development tools dictate a number of conventions.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I think.

I expect this is done by someone who was burned by a `'</script>'` and got too protective.