# Why is this script element broken up into multiple document.write() calls?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

I have frequently seen the following statement:

```
document.write("<scr");
document.write("ipt language=\"Javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"source url\"></scr");
document.write("ipt>");
```

What is the advantage of this? Why don't people write the whole script, as below?

```
document.write("<script ");
```

Comment: Would question the jQuery title and tag. Have modified accordingly

Comment: @James Wiseman: I don’t read jQuery but just query.

Comment: Apologies. Been looking at jQuery all day! Would still argue that 'query' was not an appropriate tag, though.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/2913.htm

> Depending on the browser, the amount of other preceding javascript,
>   and how well-formed the overall code
>   is, this is done to prevent the parser
>   from interpreting the  and
>    tags as executeable code
>   rather than as a string to be written.
>
> I have found that it just saves headaches down the road if you do this
>   when using script to write script
>   tags.

Comment: Rather than split across multiple *document.write()* calls, it's usually enough to just "invalidate" the closing tag, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"><\/script>`.  The HTML parser will not recognize `<\/script>` as a closing script tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably done to comply with the standards – but they did it wrong in this case.

From the [description of *CDATA* data type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata):

> Although the `STYLE` and `SCRIPT` elements use CDATA for their data model, for these elements, CDATA must be handled differently by user agents. Markup and entities must be treated as raw text and passed to the application as is. **The first occurrence of the character sequence "`</`" (end-tag open delimiter) is treated as terminating the end of the element's content. In valid documents, this would be the end tag for the element.**

So they rather should have split the end-tag open delimiter `</` like this:

```
document.write("<script language=\"Javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"source url\"><" + "/script>");
```

Comment: +1 - `<\/script>` works too, so you don't have to use string concatenation.

Comment: @Andy E: I know. I just used concatenation as well as it was used in the example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. When you see such code, it means they are generating certain parts of the page ***dynamically*** otherwise yes they could have easily written in `<script>` tags just below that.

And sometimes, such code is used for ***malicious*** purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this how some people attempt to get past antivirus's script scanners?

To answer your question:
There's no gain from doing this.  In fact, it's actually slower, since you're invoking more functions, creating more string objects, and appending more strings.

For older browsers, I guess it might be similar to usage of `<!-- <script> blargh </script> //-->`

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's some kind of primitive code obfuscation to sneak in script into dynamic pages. If a website filters user input for the string "`<script`" for example, this piece of code here would still go through.

Most likely this is some attempt to inject malicious code somewehere.