# why break this up javascript fragment?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

I don't really do Javascript programming and was hard to google this but have seen something like this in a couple of different places (by good developers):

```
document.writeln('<scr'+'ipt src="'+pcheck+'" type="text/javascript"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

With the split always between the r and the i. What does this achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to prevent any script blockers from loading this script, because they cannot find the "script" word within the text.

Comment: That may be a side effect but is not the intention. It allows the browser to render a page with script-generated script. It doens't matter where the split is as long as the browser is not given '<script'.

Comment: @DanIveson is right. The correct reason is explained here: http://mths.be/etago