# Dynamically appending the user input to <script src= " "> from a textbox in Java Script

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript, I tried searching for a solution to my problem online, but wasn't successful.

I need to append the user's input from a textbox, after `onclick` of a button to 'src' attribute of `<script>` element in the same file. How can I do this?

```
<script id="url " type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=USER INPUT&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=30&format=5">
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick= ? />
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You realise that JavaScript is client-side, right? Which means the server-side asp.net (I assume?) is irrelevant; please show the rendered html as seen by the browser (as in 'view source').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Apologise but your question is a little bit unclear.
If I got it correctly, you just want to "add" to the src attribute of the script tag whatever the user write into the textbox, is that correct ?
If this is the case, I'd do something along this line:

```
(function( doc, $ ){
    $.call( doc, 'Button1' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        var script = $.call( doc, 'url' );
        script.src += $.call( doc, 'TextBox1' ).value;
    });
}(document, document.getElementById ));
```

PS: I've aliased the document and the documentElementById function to save some chars..

Comment: I am trying to integrate YouTube in my application through YouTube API JSON.... The below link has a documentation for YouTube JSON codelab, under that "on your own" section, it says i need to add a function that does dynamic script injection. developers.google.com/youtube/code#JavaScript

Comment: first question (then I'll go to have a look at the link you just provided): are you using jQuery or some other DOM-enhancing library ? (second question, if answer to first is "no": are you keen using one ?)

Comment: Ok, I've read the doc. you then have 2 options, modifying the src attribute (and this is precisely what the code I provided does) or to create a script tag on the fly for including content. What I don't understand is how all of this relate to your example. You stated that you have an input box and a button and when you press the button you want to modify the script tag src attribute, appending to id the content of the textbox. Is this solving your problem ? (this is what the code I provided is for).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion... I tried creating script tag on the fly and it seem to be working...
Yes, I have a Input box and the user input in appended in link provided in src attribute. Created a function to add script tag and called the function through 'onsubmit' attribute of <form>...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion... I tried creating script tag on the fly and it seem to be working...
Yes, I have a Input box and the user input in appended in link provided in src attribute. Created a function to add script tag and called the function through 'onsubmit' attribute of <form>...

Thanks again!!

Comment: if you're satisfied with it, can you please vote my answer and close the question ? thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="user_input" />
<div id="start">START</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javasscript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#start').on('click', function() {

            $.getScript('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+$('user_input').val()+'&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos2&max-results=30&format=5');

        })
    })
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/SvaXc/2/

Comment: Um, did you see a [tag:jquery] tag?

Comment: Nope, but since I don't know anything about the environment and to solve the problem I just added a jQuery tag. It is extremely helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what it is you're trying to achieve, but here are several techniques:

1. Dynamically retrieve the JavaScript you need (via an AJAX call) and invoke it with eval() -> this interprets and executes the JavaScript code.  This can be very dangerous so proceed with caution.
2. Dynamically add a <script> element with the src set to the script you want, and append this element to the  element of the document.
3. If you're using jQuery, you can use the $.getScript() function to retrieve and execute JavaScript on the fly.

Take a look at this Stack Overflow question as well:
[How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)

Although old, here is a good description of some different techniques: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Comment: I am trying to integrate YouTube in my application through YouTube API JSON.... The below link has a documentation for YouTube JSON codelab, under that "on your own" section, it says i need to add a function that does dynamic script injection.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a new script tag on-the-fly (then you can remove the one you provided in the markup), you can do this (I'm using jQuery here to simplify code, otherwise my post would become unnecessary long):

```
(function($){
    $(document.body).append( '<script src="' + $('#TextBox1').val() + '">' );
}(jQuery));
```

If you cannot (or want to) use jQuery, you can do like so:

```
(function(doc, $) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
      var dynScript = doc.createElement('script');
      dynScript.setAttribute('src', $.call( doc, 'TextBox1' ).value );
      doc.body.appendChild( dynScript );      
  } );
}(document, document.getElementById ));
```

hope this helps.