# Run javascript src only on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is there any possibility to run javascript only when the button has been clicked. I don't care if the load might take a bit, it's just that I dont need it to load with the page.

So for example we have a button:

```
<div id="proceed"></div>
```

Then when that button has been clicked we have a popup window with 2 more buttons.

So one of the buttons from popup will be like confirm run it and second one will simply close popup.

And what I want is to run following script src:

```
src="http://fileice.net/gateway/mygate.php?id=4465766c4278366467523838"
```

When the "proceed" has been clicked.
So script will have time to load up till user read what popup message says.

So... any chances to run script src on button click?

EDIT:

The gateway conflicts with some other scripts and thats the main reason why to run it on click only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without JQuery:

```
<input type="button" onclick="loadScript('http://fileice.net/gateway/mygate.php?id=4465766c4278366467523838');" value="Proceed" />
```

In your Javascript:

```
function loadScript(script_url)
{
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.src= script_url;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: So far... after all jQuery methods, this one works great. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery`:

```
function doAction() {
    $.getScript("http://fileice.net/gateway/mygate.php?id=4465766c4278366467523838");
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="proceed" onClick="doAction()"></div>
```

Comment: sort of strange, but it redirects me to location instead of running script :]

Comment: @NenaddvL Haven't understood your aim at first. Please, check my updated answer.

Comment: Somehow I can't run it fella :-/
Guess it conflicts with jQuery as it has jQuery inside and also running in head.

Comment: .get() won't execute a script.

Comment: You also shouldn't use inline JavaScript whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
$('#proceed').click(function(){
    $.getScript('http://fileice.net/gateway/mygate.php?id=4465766c4278366467523838');
});
```

Comment: Quite interesting and simple, but conflicts with jQuery and I can't run it.

Comment: How does it conflict with jQuery? It is jQuery.

Comment: My mistake. I left jQuery and removed an youtube script instead. It was conflict with another jquery script.
(Gateway includes jQuery inside thats why I thought jQuery conflicts with older version of jQuery - 2x jQuery included)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can get your answer here .. [How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)..
what they are doing on load you can do it on button click

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth noting that the script tag also has a defer attribute which

> Delays the execution of a script

until after the page is loaded. [More](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

It might be a viable option if you don't want to have to manually be involved to load the script and you can load it after the rest of the page is ready.

Best of luck!

Comment: Defer simply tries to delay execution of a script until the page has loaded. The OP wants to run the script on the click of a div.

Comment: The OP said '...it's just that I dont need it to load with the page.'  Defer, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work) is usually occurs when the document is fully loaded.  I was simply offering an alternative since his request for a 'clickable load' functionality seemed like a work around for the problem