# Conditionally serve javascript with Foundation Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm working with the Foundation Framework and I was wondering if there are any callbacks or functions that will deliver jQuery or javascript based on the current screen size or media query.

For example

```
if ('screen_size' =< 'small') {
  // do some jquery
}
```

Not sure if this is possible.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any mixins for it, but you can [manually load a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load) via jquery, based on the window width (maybe attach it to a resize event as well as to onload?)

```
if( $(window).width() <= 1024 ){
  $.getScript("test.js", function(){
    alert("Running test.js");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really love the jRespond plugin. Very useful for this sort of thing.

https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond