# How to replace the special characters in js

Tags: javascript

**i want add this to my html,but it didn't work .**

```
var html = '<div id="youkuplayer"></div>'
+'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.youku.com/jsapi">'
    +'player = new YKU.Player("youkuplayer",{'
            +'client_id: "81dab93633c39ff0",'
            +'vid: "XNjQ4Nzk5MTA0_ev_1",'
            +'width: "240",'
            +'height: "200",'
            +'autoplay: false,'
            +'show_related: false'
        +'});'
    +'</script>';
```

$("#added_video").css("display","block").append(html);

but if i use a static html include this,it works.

Comment: you can't add js to a script tag that also has a src. It's one or the other. to achieve what you want you will need to split to 2 script tags.

Comment: but if i use a static html include this,it works.

Comment: if split to 2 script tags it hava cross domain problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the SCRIPT tag, which jQuery chokes on.

See this answer for some possible solutions: [How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

Some error in your code,you need add `'</script><script>'` in your code like this:

```
var html = '<div id="youkuplayer"></div>'
    +'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.youku.com/jsapi"></script><script>'
        +'player = new YKU.Player("youkuplayer",{'
                +'client_id: "81dab93633c39ff0",'
                +'vid: "XNjQ4Nzk5MTA0_ev_1",'
                +'width: "240",'
                +'height: "200",'
                +'autoplay: false,'
                +'show_related: false'
            +'});'
        +'</script>';
```