# Add recaptcha to a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recaptcha

I have the following snippet:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <div id='mydiv'>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to add "recaptcha" inside `#mydiv` usign a javascript code given at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display just before `</body>`:

I tried to use the following code:

```
<script>
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeZBs8SAAAAAFnpP1frAONoZH-I-W9HOm0RQgV0';
mydiv.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. It only paste the script code. It doesn't run it.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: And did you try anything else? Like placing your code just before </form> instead?

Comment: i tried with these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml
but i could not find the correct answer.

Comment: I want to do it with a script placed at the beginning or at the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go taken from the example code on your link see fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/GVwZ4/1/

in a div

http://jsfiddle.net/GVwZ4/2/

```
<body>
      <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeZBs8SAAAAAFnpP1frAONoZH-I-    W9HOm0RQgV0">
  </script>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: that is what i want, BUT using a script that is outside of the div

Comment: Well that would be dynamically loading the tag why do you want to do this. This is possible if you use an external .js file see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load

Comment: Thanks,, but i did it with jQuery. I used created a div with the script first and then .appendTo to move it to mydiv