# Inserting a <script> tag dynamically via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I'm trying to add a widget to the page in run-time. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load), I wrote the code below. Unfortunately, it doesn't show anything. Can anybody tell me why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "https://widgets.factiva.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.ashx?tkn=LDyKkRh5SFskMPuGz6nika6Sg%2bqurZ4vspn0e1OvlEQc6JqLTdcyY8%2btC7a9zO0Z42ta%2f%2fl7QbCByRVbs7TTuQ%3d%3d%7c2&typ=0&st=1&target=7";
        // Use any selector
        $(".testWidget").append(s);
    });
</script>

<div class="testWidget">

</div>
```

If I put the same script as below, it works and shows some information on the page. However, I should insert the script dynamically, not as static.

```
<div class="testWidget">
<script src="https://widgets.factiva.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.ashx?tkn=LDyKkRh5SFskMPuGz6nika6Sg%2bqurZ4vspn0e1OvlEQc6JqLTdcyY8%2btC7a9zO0Z42ta%2f%2fl7QbCByRVbs7TTuQ%3d%3d%7c2&typ=0&st=1&target=7" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach works of me, which is to say that the script gets inserted into the div.

Comment: Do you see something like this? http://i59.tinypic.com/qqrakn.png (Afghanistan News) I tested it on IE 11 and Chrome, <div> tag is empty

Comment: It's an issue with asynchronously loading a script that uses the `document.write` method. You would have to rewrite the `document.write` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting this warning in the console, `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.` Here's a way around that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // Save a copy of the document.write method
      var oldWrite = document.write;

      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = "https://widgets.factiva.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.ashx?tkn=LDyKkRh5SFskMPuGz6nika6Sg%2bqurZ4vspn0e1OvlEQc6JqLTdcyY8%2btC7a9zO0Z42ta%2f%2fl7QbCByRVbs7TTuQ%3d%3d%7c2&typ=0&st=1&target=7";

      // After script is loaded, revert document.write to the original
      s.onload = function () {
        document.write = oldWrite;
      };

      var $testWidget = $('.testWidget');

      // Redefine document.write to make the script's call work
      document.write = function (html) {
        $testWidget.html(html);
      };

      $testWidget.append(s);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It works! One more thing. If I append some code after appending the script, it shows it until the scripts is loaded. Then it removes it. Like this one: `$testWidget.append("<a href=\"http://sample" target=\"_blank\">More Info</a>");`. How can I append more code into the same `<div>`?

Comment: Oh, you can change `$testWidget.html(html);` to `.prepend` or `.append`

Comment: Just noticed. It's good in IE11 but the script is shown on the page two times in IE9. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The script tag you include programatically has to be parsed by the browser. Just by inserting the script tag the included code is not parsed by the JavaScript interpreter.

If you explain what you want to finally achieve I am pretty sure that must be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to get some News data from a service provider. It looks like this when it works: http://i59.tinypic.com/qqrakn.png (Afghanistan News). You can test it by running the second code block