# Append javascript script to head doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a script tag with a script on the head of a page, but I am appending the code and it doesnt work. Probably because the page is already running.

How can I have something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        $('head').append('&ltscript&gtconsole.log("running")&lt/script&gt');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtjmy5gy/6/

Comment: So basically you want to write JS using JS. Why would you do this? You could just define a function and call it when needed.

Comment: &lt; and &gt; should be used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load

Comment: @HoschNok I'm building a chrome extension and I need to inject a script dynamically.

Comment: @GEspinha Chrome already has functions for this - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/jtjmy5gy/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').on('click', function () {
     $('<script>').text('console.log("running")').appendTo('head');
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

call Function using above Example    : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/jtjmy5gy/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('a').on('click', function () {
     $('<script>').text('test()').appendTo('head');
   });
});

function test(){
  console.log("running")
}
```

**Edit**  . you can also append script tag like below : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/jtjmy5gy/16/)

```
$("head").append($("<script />", {
   text: 'test()',
}))

$("head").append($("<script />", {
   html: 'test()',
}))

$("head").append($("<script />", {
   src: url,
}))
```

Comment: What if I have a larger script to add to the head?

Comment: you need to write every thing in text(). or you can directly call a function

Comment: May i know the reason why you want to code like this . when you can use any function or any logic base on events ??

Comment: I need this code to run a couple of scripts dynamically through a chrome extension, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script into a separate file, then use `$.getScript` to load and run it.

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(){
    alert("Running test.js");
});
```

Source: Rocket Hazmat

[How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)

Comment: The script in question doesn't have an `src`, it's just an inline script

Comment: Yes, I its just an inline script