# Lazy Load For Blog Posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

So I'm trying so so hard to find something for JavaScript or jQuery where I can use a lazy loading plugin or SOMETHING that goes a little like this:

```
if .post IS_NOT_IN_VIEW do{
dont_load();
 }else{
load();
}
```

I could've made that better xD. But hopefully you can understand what I mean by that. I just want something that'll STOP the loading of my content with a class of "post" but it'll load it when the user has the content in view.

Thank you if you can help... I had already posted a question like this but people just had problems with the post and I guess people just didn't even bother to look at it seeing it had 6 or 7 comments...

Comment: Ajax - j query can load when required

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Keep in mind I'm only a beginner sort of developer. I know my HTML, some css, some JavaScript and jQuery, but I need actual code to understand what you mean please.

Comment: This is not a free coding service. Just gave you a pointer to look in the right direction

Comment: Alright then thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ajax addresses your question.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can load resources using this.

**HTML**:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: "some_url",
    dataType: "html"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    alert( "HTML content: " + html);
});
```

Or for json just change the dataType to json.

If you want to lazily load **javascript**:

[How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)

Has some helpful answers.