# JavaScript in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need a help with Contact Form 7 and additional settings.

I would like to add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.js?mid=0000&refer=example_name"></script>
```

to

```
on_sent_ok:
```

I tried to do it in many ways but it is not working.

Comment: `on_sent_ok` expects a string of executable JS code. So if you want to load an external script, go research/look up how insert a script element dynamically, f.e. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load  And remember, the JS code you assign to `on_sent_ok` must be a valid JS string, so careful with line breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how I should do it. I tried to add script but it is not working. Someone can help me? :(

Comment: In WP, you should have jQuery available, so using getScript should work, try something like `on_sent_ok: '$.getScript("https://example.js?mid=0000&refer=example_name")'`

Comment: Yes! It's working! Thank you for help. Good of you! Thank you @CBroe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_sent_ok` expects a string of executable JS code.

So to load and execute an external script, you can use jQuery's getScript, like so:

```
on_sent_ok: '$.getScript("https://example.js?mid=0000&refer=example_name‌​")'
```