# How to include a script if element has a class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Let's say I have:

```
<body class="hello">
```

How can we do something like the following?

```
if($("body").hasClass("hello")) {
  <script src="/demo_js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
}
```

I was wondering if maybe doing something like:

```
if($("body").hasClass("hello")) {
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></'+'script>');
}
```

That looks fine but it's a mixup of `jQuery` and `JS` and I am not sure if that's the correct way anyway.

It'd be even better if this could be done via the backend in `php` but I am not sure how to check if an `element` has a `class` in `php` neither how to tell it to `include` a `script` if it does.

How would you approach it?

One trick in `php` I thought is the following but then again, is there any better way?

```
<?php
  $hello = "hello";
  if($hello) { ?>
    <script...
<?php } ?>
<body class="<?php echo $hello; ?>">
```

Comment: Forget `document.write()`. Use DOM manipulation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write

Comment: @JakubBoucek ok so are you suggesting basically to write a html element like `document.createElement('script');` and work with it's attribute src afterwards? What's the difference?

Comment: See the linked answer in my previous comment. Difference is big one: `document.write()` you can call only when is page loadging, not later and it have more negative sife-effects. DOM access is clean.

Comment: @JakubBoucek I see, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically insert a <script> tag via jQuery after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857874/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-script-tag-via-jquery-after-page-load)

Comment: why a down vote? And no it's not a duplicate, I have provided my own solution, I was asking if there was a better way or in php.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function for this is `$.getScript`.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript( "/demo_js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js" )
```