# How to dynamically add codepen embed and ensure it is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, codepen

**Desired Behaviour**

Show embedded codepen in an environment where registered users can edit page content.

There may be more than one codepen added to a page.

**Actual Behaviour**

When adding a pen to the DOM, the pen does not display, only a link to the pen is displayed.

**Steps To Reproduce**

*Note: the steps below are just to demonstrate the logic that would take place in my own environment, ie a registered user editing content on a website.*

01)  Go to this randomly selected [pen](https://codepen.io/ste-vg/pen/oKYjKV)
02)  Click on the `Embed` link at the bottom right of the page
03)  Copy contents from the `HTML (recommended)` tab
04)  Go to https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens
05)  Open Chrome developer tools, and replace a paragraph element with the embed code
06)  The pen will not be displayed, only a link like:

```
See the Pen [pen_name] by [pen_author] on CodePen
```

**Question**

What additional steps do I need to make to ensure the codepen is rendered?

Given that the format of the embed code is:

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-theme-id="37516" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="ste-vg" data-slug-hash="oKYjKV" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Clip Clop Clippity Clop">
    <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/ste-vg/pen/oKYjKV/">
            Clip Clop Clippity Clop</a> by Steve Gardner (<a href="https://codepen.io/ste-vg">@ste-vg</a>)
        on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

it does seem a bit presumptuous to expect the script will just do its job when pasted in the page.

If that is the case, how do I dynamically add the contents (including the script tag) and ensure it is executed?

**EDIT**

I just came across this [answer from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857899), which suggests this format:

```js
$.getScript("https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js", function(){
    console.log("running new js!");
});
```

and when I run that in Chrome dev tools, after pasting the embed code in the DOM, the pen is rendered.

- Is there anything wrong with this approach?
- Why doesn't pasting the embed code in the DOM 'just work'?
- Is the script file referenced in the embed code unique to the pen?
- Or could you just add the script to your page once and it would handle all embedded pens (both existing and those dynamically added)?

I tried adding this to `<head>`:

```html
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

and having it there doesn't seem to parse existing or dynamically added embed code.

They still just display the message:

```
See the Pen [pen_name] by [pen_author] on CodePen
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

With script referenced in `<head>`, I tried calling this after dynamically adding the HTML to the DOM:

```
__CPEmbed()
```

And it renders the codepens!

I'm not sure if it is a legitimate way to do it, but I came across `__CPEmbed` at the end of the article here:

https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/prefill-embeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've figured it out! Yes, `__CPEmbed()` is the official API for triggering the iframe insertion. You can even feed it a specific selector if there are certain embeds you want to target: `__CPEmbed('.my-codepen-embed')`

It's triggered by default when the `document.readyState !== 'loading'`, but you can call it at any time. Multiple calls should not affect already converted embeds.

I couldn't find this in our regular Embed documentation anymore, so I'm making a note to update that.

Thanks!

Comment: hello - has this changed at all, i *just* started getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: __CPEmbed is not defined` when calling `__CPEmbed();` - it was working yesterday I think, and it is possible i changed something elsewhere in a recent coding frenzy and that is causing it, but just thought i'd ask, thanks.  script is linked to in template html page:  `<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>`

Comment: specifically, the error is:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: __CPEmbed is not defined at Object.success (common.js:1945) at fire (jquery.js:3291) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3421) at done (jquery.js:9533) at XMLHttpRequest.eval (jquery.js:9785)`

Comment: @user1063287 There was a temporary issue with the CodePen embed script ( ei.js ) that has since been fixed. It should work as expected now.

Comment: thank you @shshaw - i can confirm this error message is no longer displaying, thank you.