# output string as a script from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string in following format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "fivestar": { "titleUser": "Your rating: ", "titleAverag.... } });//--><!]]></script>
```

How can I output it from jquery script as a script in a page? I have tried

```
var elem = $mystring;
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

But it does not work. Apparently there are some characters that shoud be escaped? Thank you for help

Comment: You don't need to do that comment and CDATA stuff any more. Hasn't been needed for at least a decade.

Comment: @Barmar I know but this is unfortunately the string that I have to work with.

Comment: The argument to `appendChild()` needs to be a DOM element, not an HTML string.

Comment: If you have HTML you need to assign to `.innerHTML`. But that won't execute scripts.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It will execute scripts when you use its `.html()` method.

Comment: @Barmar no I can not use jQuery. Javascript is my only option

Comment: Why can the script you're trying to insert using jQuery but you can't?

Comment: @Barmar It is a string created elsewhere in system. I am just working with output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626155/1024832

Comment: @Marc That uses jQuery, they have to use vanilla JS.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm the upvoter on your comment.  Seems to me this person _can_ use jQuery since the code being inserted relies upon it, despite poster saying he/she cannot. But you're right; says only vanilla JS.

Comment: @Marc I think he's saying that this has to work in more general contexts, so maybe the script being inserted doesn't use jQuery, and jQuery isn't loaded into the page. The code shown is just an example.