# jQuery - Input field calculation not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I have a form with fields that are automatically totaled when values are added, it works fine in ie 6,7 +8 and FF but the field is blank in Safari and Chrome - any ideas??

```
// total income
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("input.add").change(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            jQuery('.add').each(function() {
                var Total = sum += Number(jQuery(this).val());
                jQuery("#input_38").val(Total);
```

});

```
        });​​​​​​​​​ <---  Chrome has a problem with this 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL'


        // total expenditure
        jQuery("input.add_ex").change(function () {
            var sumEx = 0;
            jQuery('.add_ex').each(function() {
                var TotalEx = sumEx += Number(jQuery(this).val());
                jQuery("#input_70").val(TotalEx);
            });


        });​​​​​​​​​

        //grand total

        jQuery("input.add_ex").change(function () {                 // when total expenditure field changes

            var totalInc = Number(jQuery("#input_38").val()); // store total income as var
            var totalExp = Number(jQuery("#input_70").val()); // store total expenditure as var

            jQuery("#input_75").val(totalInc - totalExp); // change grand total

        });




    });//end
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/eG8SY/). Are you getting any errors on your console?

Comment: Which field in particular? Do you get any arror in console? Could you post a snippet of your html too?

Comment: @Nalum - None at all in chrome or firebug

Comment: @mamoo - the fiddle above has the basics, it just totals fields with the classes '.add' and '.add_ex'

Comment: @Nalum - Actually its saying Unexpected token ILLEGAL for the closing brackets after jQuery("#input_38").val(Total);

Comment: SOLVED : Switched from Mac to PC notepad and found a bunch of random characters that needed deleted, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Since the example of Nalum is working maybe some hidden characters are messing up your script.

Try to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to see if it spots the same problem, and try to remove some spaces in that line.

edit:

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit).