# Multi step form validation of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:

    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    const button = document.getElementById()('button')
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == y.length) {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += "invalid";
            button.disabled = true
                // and set the current valid status to false
            valid = false;
        } else {
            button.disabled = false;
        }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    #regForm {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 100px auto;
        font-family: Raleway;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 70%;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
    
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    input {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Raleway;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }
    
    label {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type=radio] {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .tab input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
        background-color: red;
        color: #fff2f2;
    }
    /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
    
    input.invalid {
        background-color: #ffdddd;
    }
    /* Hide all steps by default: */
    
    .tab {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .btn {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
        border: #000000 solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Raleway;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    button:focus {
        background-color: #000000;
        border-width: 1px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    button:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
    #prevBtn {
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
    }
    /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
    
    .step {
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    
    .step.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
    
    .step.finish {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
    }
```

```html
    <form id="regForm" action="" method="GET">
        <h1>Register:</h1>
        <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
        <div class="tab">
            <!-- name should same for each group and value should different it will based on option value (we select) -->
            <input type="radio" id="1" name="Gender" value="Male">
            <label for="1">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="2" name="Gender" value="Female">
            <label for="2">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="3" name="Gender" value="Other">
            <label for="3">Other</label>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="4" name="Hobbies" value="Reading">
            <label for="4">Reading</label>
            <input type="radio" id="5" name="Hobbies" value="Dancing">
            <label for="5">Dancing</label>
            <input type="radio" id="6" name="Hobbies" value="Nothing">
            <label for="6">Nothing</label>

        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="7" name="Sports" value="Cricket">
            <label for="7">Cricket</label>
            <input type="radio" id="8" name="Sports" value="Football">
            <label for="8">Football</label>
            <input type="radio" id="9" name="Sports" value="Volleyball">
            <label for="9">Volleyball</label>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" id="10" name="Living" value="Home">
            <label for="10">Home</label>
            <input type="radio" id="11" name="Living" value="PG">
            <label for="11">PG</label>
            <input type="radio" id="12" name="Living" value="Hostel">
            <label for="12">Hostel</label>
        </div>
        <!-- Submit working only if having previous button -->
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
            <div style="float:right;">

                <button type="button" class="submit" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)" disabled>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
        </div>
```

Hello
I'm working on form validation of radio buttons. I have a very long form and I am validating each field of that form. The pasted one is some of it.
**Requirement**: I need help in form validation of radio buttons. I want to disable next button until radio button is checked I tried many ways but not getting exact results as my requirement. Please help to solve me this. Thanks in advance.

Note: If possible in **jQuery** please do the need. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Tharun check this post for validation radio button https://stackoverflow.com/a/10339240/14457833

Comment: Thanks !but i tried this its not working .I don't know why