# not the expected 'effect' when using jquery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an unexpected effect and some other bugs when trying to use show/hide with mouseover and mouseout.

What I was trying to do is have a box (div) and when you would mouse over it, another box would appear and slide to the right.

Here's the fiddle for it 
http://jsfiddle.net/XtXGR/

Now there's two problems with it. One is the flickering and the other is that it appears by growing from the top-left corner and what I want it to do is appear from the left.

Any help would be greatly be appreciated. Thanks

I think I know what causes the flickering from the similar questions but I still need help with the other issue. Thanks!

Oh also just so you know the context in which this will be used is on a page with a table of items and each item would be the object in the fiddle link I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that moving over a different child element of the container will trigger a `mouseout` and `mouseover` combination, which is why you see the element expanding and collapsing. IE circumvented this with the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, which act exactly like the CSS `:hover`.

Speaking of which, the jQuery [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function has this feature too. You should use that instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

According to the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) API, you should use the [`slide`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) effect to get what you want.

Your final code should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XtXGR/28/

Comment: that is perfect. just what I was looking for! It works perfectly in fiddle but for some reason I'm getting an error when inserting it into my own file? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL for chrome dev tool. I have looked over and over but can't find this token it speaks of.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit

Comment: haha of course. thanks! I couldn't even find the white space that was causing the error but I slowly just retyped it, testing step by step, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

If you want to do a fadein/out this would be better:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.item_container").hover(function() {
         $("div.item_body").fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
         $("div.item_body").fadeOut(500);
    });

});
```

​
Also, you should probably float the div `.item_body` to the left..

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/XtXGR/33/

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS3 transitions instead?

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/EVDj6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  Using [slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) will give you the slide from default left effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.item_container").on('hover',function(){
        $("div.item_body").toggle('slide',500);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XtXGR/25/

Answer (score 0):

There were many issues in your code.  The href's were invalid and the floating of the elements was not 100% correct.  One of the main issues was that you had display:none in your CSS.  Bring that dispay:none out and of the CSS and put it inline on the item you want to show/hide.  When its default state is "hide" then you need to bring the display:none inline.

Look at this fiddle to get a better idea of how to go about this with a bit more valid syntax:
http://jsfiddle.net/fH3EC/1/

Answer (score 0):

I made something fast, you can go crazy with it :) The animation is pretty smooth, I hope it's useful for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/XtXGR/50/