# Creating a custom file upload with jQuery, HTML and CSS

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have this small problem with a website I'm designing. It's fairly over, but I think the jQuery is the problem here.

The code is as follows:

```
<img src="files/register_page/upload_photo/body.png" id="upload">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

And the jQuery is the following, in the  part of the document:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
      $("#upload").click( function(){
          $('#file_upload').click();
      });
    });
```

However, upon clicking the img, nothing happens, where a file upload dialog should pop up.
Please, if you need any more information or something, let me know. If not, what could the problem be here? I'm using jQuery 1.8.0.

Comment: You did not set an "onclick" action for "file_upload".

Comment: @JohnnyMopp do you know how file inputs work?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yeah, you don't have to set the onclick when using jquery I believe.

Comment: Oh, I see :) http://jsfiddle.net/JQBYM/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This is weird, it works in the jsfiddle, but not for me when I program it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using HTML5 [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) element:

```
<label for="file_upload"><img src="files/register_page/upload_photo/body.png" id="upload"></label>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YZgDB/1/)

Works in Chrome, IE and Opera but not FF.

Browsers tend to limit what you can do with `input type="file"`. The label element redirects the focus to the input with the id property equal to its `for` property, so this is an workaround to trigger the invisible element.

---

Modern browsers have alleviated a good part of those restrictions though, so you can trigger the `.click()` without problem.

You may however, change the CSS hack to hide it without using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` for back-compat with older browsers. Either

```
position:absolute; top:-100px;
```

Or

```
opacity:0;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
width:0; height:0;
```

Can hide the element without using the `display` or `visibility` CSS properties.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YZgDB/9/)

---

Also, here's an workaround for the label element on FF, you can change the `visibility:hidden` by `opacity:0` and:

```
$('#file_upload').focus(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YZgDB/8/). But this should be unnecessary if the primary script works fine.

Comment: This worked! Amazing, could you explain why it works like this?

Comment: Oh I see :P Have you got any suggestions on making it work for FF too? I think this could be important for many users ;/

Comment: @jslvtr Yup, I'm trying some more hackish jQuery, let's see if I succeed in a min or two.

Comment: @jslvtr This may seem a little awkward but, your original code seems to work fine on FF/Chrome/IE? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YZgDB/5/)

Comment: @jslvtr In which browser? Anyway try changing the `visibility:hidden` by `opacity:0`, I posted the workaround for the label element in FF on my answer. By any chance, are these input elements added dynamically?

Comment: I am getting an error in the last }); for both jscript snippets, and I don't know why. Maybe that is the reason it doesn't work?
The error is unexpected token ILLEGAL.
It works in no browser if I remove the <label>, in which case it only works in chrome/IE.
The elements are not added dynamically

Comment: @jslvtr Exactly, syntax errors kill the script tag. Post the full code on http://jsfiddle.net or try to validate it at http://jshint.com and it'll show the syntax error. `=]`

Comment: This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/mZW3g0md
Now I'm not getting any errors, weirdly enough.

Comment: @jslvtr Also, you may have a problem with invisible white spaces, that's usually the cause of that bug. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4404547/1331430 Go pressing the arrow keys slowly by the end of the script and check if there aren't any invisible characters. `=]`

Comment: It works now... This is so strange! I had been using focus instead of click after changing it from visibility:hidden to opacity:0, but now, with opacity:0 and click it is working. I shall check other browsers too and come back

Comment: Yup, I already checked `.click()` in FF/Chrome/IE/Opera. Browsers are slightly skeptic about what you can do with `input type="file"`, so polices may change in the future. Here's a [CSS+JS hack](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom) that also works cross-browser (but jQuery should suffice for now IMO). `=]`

Comment: @jslvtr Here's more info why `display:none` and `visibility:none` didn't allow to trigger it in some browsers: [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7302101/1331430). Seems like this restriction has been alleviated in modern browsers, but you may use one of those hacks (`position:abolute;top:-100px;`, `opacity:0, height:0` etc) to make it invisible without using display or visibility to support old browsers.

Comment: Alright, added my final revision for now, comment if it bugs in any browser. `=]`

Comment: It works perfectly in all browsers! Thank you very much for your time Fabricio :P I really appreciate it