# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL? Looks Fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected token ILLEGAL in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit)

Ive been looking at this and cannot see a problem, it works in jfiddle - just not on the site!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
            fixed = true;
            $('#menu-scroll').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
        }
    } else {
        if( fixed ) {
            fixed = false;
            $('#menu-scroll').css({display:'none'});
        }
    }
});​
</script>
```

link to the site is http://mtro.es/7

Comment: Your page has several 404 errors. Check it with a dev console.

Comment: There is indeed an invisible character after the last `;`.

Comment: Specifically [`U+200B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you, Didn't realise there was a hidden character!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is no html element with id "menu-scroll". You check..

Comment: Syntax errors aren't thrown depending on whether elements do or do not exist; moreover, jQuery never throws errors in case elements do not exist.