# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, syntax-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected token ILLEGAL in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit)

I wrote a simple script for a hover over effect here http://jsfiddle.net/paDmg/368/ for this site http://avuedesigns.com/new/ - It works on jsfiddle, but I am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

in my JavaScript when I put it live. It's on line 29 it is telling me which is the closing marks });​

```
$('#hover-grid .indiv-cell').hover(function() {

//set variables to current cell attributes
var cellHeader = $(this).attr('data-hoverheader');
var cellText = $(this).attr('data-hovertext');
var replacementImg = $(this).find('a img').attr('data-replacementimg');
var oringinalImg = $(this).find('a img').attr('src');

//save original image to data variable
$(this).data('origImg', oringinalImg);

//add remove classes
$('#hover-grid .indiv-cell').removeClass('newClass');
$(this).addClass('newClass', 1000);
$(this).find('a img').hide().attr('src', replacementImg).fadeIn(300);
$('.master-cell h1').hide().text(cellHeader).fadeIn(300);
$('.master-cell p').hide().text(cellText).fadeIn(300);

//return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a img').hide().attr('src', $(this).data('origImg')).fadeIn(10);
});​
```

Comment: Check your JS for invalid embedded characters like nulls, that may get stripped off by JSfiddle.

Comment: Your code only has 25 lines...

Comment: @Nadim Dayoub: FYI http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731

Comment: if you google for "unexpected token illegal" the top 10 hits would all fix your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have embedded illegal characters. Look in your JS with a hex editor and look for any characters that aren't visible ASCII characters. They may be getting stripped off by JSfiddle

See [Chrome Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: Thanks, removed the last line and retyped it and no more error. Now I got to figure out why it is not working now...