# Getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL while clicking on Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Below is the html code which i am using

```
<a onclick="submit_details('143','v
VASANT','PATIL','8275053468','425201');" href="javascript:;">2</a>
```

Below is the function call its going

```
function submit_details(pid,fname,lname,phone,zip){
    $("#sp_value").val(pid);
    $("#sf_value").val(fname);
    $("#sl_value").val(lname);
    $("#sph_value").val(phone);
    $("#sz_value").val(zip);
    $("#detail_form").submit();
}
```

whicle clicking i am getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  in the error console

Comment: there is a line break between `v VASANT`

Comment: there is no break between them. Since dud to less space it is coming to next line

Comment: your generated html should not break it like this.... keep it in one line and check

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hGmk4/1/

Comment: yeah that was the problem its solved thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

make it in single line

```
 <a onclick="submit_details('143','v VASANT','PATIL','8275053468','425201');" href="javascript:;">2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have embedded illegal characters in your code.

see :

[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680072/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

(i am assuming you formatted your function text to fit well on two lines for the sake of posting, but still...)
also, while calling the function, there should not be a newline.It should be

```
<a onclick="submit_details('143','v VASANT','PATIL','8275053468','425201');" href="javascript:;">2</a>
```

otherwise it might give different errors (based on where you have entered the newline, like interminated string constant error, in your syntax)