# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL onclick mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that this is question has been asked many times before but I can't find any similar case like mine.

I want to call a javascript function on an input type button control I'm doing it like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="FormatApplicationMessage(@application.StatusID, '@application.IssueMessage')" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />
```

but I always got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

This is the generated html :

```
<input type="button" onclick="FormatApplicationMessage(5, 'Please provide a copy of your CV')" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />
```

I tried to do this:

```
<input type="button" onclick='FormatApplicationMessage(@application.StatusID, "@application.IssueMessage")' class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />
```

But I get the same error message

any hacks ?

**EDIT**

Here is `FormatApplicationMessage` implementation:

```
function FormatApplicationMessage(statusID, issueMsg) {
    //declined
    if (statusID == 4) {
        $('#ApplicationMessageLabel').val("Message");
    }
        //Update Required
    else if (statusID == 5) {
        $('#ApplicationMessageLabel').val("Message");
    }
    //Approved
    else if (statusID == 6) {
        $('#ApplicationMessageLabel').val("Message");
    }
    $('#ApplicationMessage').show();
}
```

Comment: Is `application` defined as a symbol? Does it show up on intellisense? Or rather: what is `application` supposed to be? Is `FormatApplicationMessage` defined as a `function`?

Comment: @bash.d what do you mean by defined as a symbol ?

Comment: When you type `@application` in your view, does intellisense show it or suggest it as a name?

Comment: @bash.d yes sir it suggests its name

Comment: @bash.d and yes FormatApplicationMessage is defined as a function

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what your trying to do here. You pass `issueMsg` to a function and then never use it. And no matter what the value of `statusID` is, you just set the value of the input with `id="ApplicationMessageLabel"` to exactly the same value. Add the message as a `data-` attribute and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1uoowpe/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of investigation finally I found the problem. The problem was very silly and quite annoying

The rendered HTML was like so:

```
<i  class="mywarning fa fa-warning (alias) fa-lg" onclick="FormatApplicationMessage(5,&quot;Return Message 
&quot;)"></i>
```

as you can see this part `&quot;)"></i>` is rendered on the next line because the string contains endlines which for some reasons it isn't legal to do so.

So to solve the problem I'd just replaced endlines by '< br >' (you can replace it by whatever symbol you like) when calling `FormatApplicationMessage` for the second parameter. Inside `FormatApplicationMessage` I restored those '< br >' to "\n" then displayed it in a text area.

USEFUL THREADS:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781537/getting-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-while-clicking-on-o)

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680072/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: @bash.d check this out

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think might go wrong:

1. `FormatApplicationMessage` is not defined as a function. Define this function with two parameters. And reference the script or define the function inline.
2. Make sure that in your view you can access `@application` and it contains your properties `StatusID` and `IssueMessage`
3. Make sure that `@application` is not part of your `@Model` or `@ViewBag`. If either is true use either `@Model.application.XYZ` or `@ViewBag.application.XYZ`

If all is defined, and you want to use `@application` inside parenthesis, use `@(application.XYZ)` otherwise the parser might get an error, so try:

```
 <input type="button" onclick='FormatApplicationMessage(@(application.StatusID), "@(application.IssueMessage)")' class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />
```

See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/ and look for **Explicit Expression**

**EDIT**

If `@Infas` is a C# class and you want to use this in JavaScript you must create the script inline in your view. You **cannot** use Razor `@`-syntax in a pure .js-file.

Comment: I already checked all your points:

1- FormatApplicationMessage is defined as a function

2- I can access application and its properties using intelliSene

3- Model is a list of applications @application is an entry in Model

Comment: See the last part of my answer

Comment: I tried to but parenthesis but I got the same error :(

Comment: <input type="button" onclick='FormatApplicationMessage(@(application.StatusID), "@(application.IssueMessage)")' class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />

Comment: Try to exchange the " with ' in your HTML -> `<input type="button" onclick="FormatApplicationMessage(@(application.StatusID), '@(application.IssueMessage)')" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />`

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Please retrieve it from the browser's debugger and post it here.

Comment: here you go 
<input type="button" onclick="FormatApplicationMessage(5, 'Please provide a copy of your CV
')" class="fa fa-search fa-lg" />

Comment: Please post the implementation of your `FormatApplicationMessage` function. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88308/discussion-between-ibrahim-amer-and-bash-d).

Comment: What is `@Infas`? Are you generating the script using MVC or is it a normal JavaScript file? If it is normal JS you **cannot** use Razor syntax in the .js file! Please replace all strings with test string constants like `'test'` and see if it works.

Comment: I am typing from mobile phone, can't chat. Please try what I suggested in my last comment.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with this function anyway I tried your suggestion but unfortunately I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Try to debug your application in the browser and find where it throws the error.

Comment: Ok sir I will try it and I will keep you updated. Thank you sir for your precious time and help I owe you a lot. +1 for being very collaborative :))

Comment: Good luck and please keep me up about your progress.