# can not close  JS popup 

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have a script who creates a popup  delays 3000 and appears in my site , the problem is that i cant remove it, here is my script

**html**

```
 <div id="growl"></div>
```

**css**

```
#growl {
position: absolute;
padding:5px;
bottom: 0;
right: 5px;
width: 320px;
z-index: 10;
}

.notice {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 30px;
 padding:5px;
 }

 .skin {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000000;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0.6;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

**the button to close**

```
 .close {
 background: transparent url('../img/egrowl.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 right: 2px;
  width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
 }
```

**my script**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

**the delay**

```
setTimeout(function() {

addNotice('<p>Do not Forget To Become A member </p><a href="subscribe.php">Subscribe</a>');

},3000);
```

**the close function**

```
$('#growl')
.find('.close')
.on('click', function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('.notice')
        .animate({
            border: 'none',
            height: 0,
            marginBottom: 0,
            marginTop: '-6px',
            opacity: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingTop: 0,
            queue: false
        }, 2000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
   });
      });
```

**settings**

```
 function addNotice(notice) {
$('<div class="notice"></div>')
    .append('<div class="skin"></div>')
    .append('<a href="#" class="close">close</a>')
    .append($('<div class="content"></div>').html(notice))
    .hide()
    .appendTo('#growl')
    .fadeIn(1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's more stuff that was wrong in your setup. I've created this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CyJRF/2/

you are binding a click event to the '.close' element, but you are doing it at $(document).ready(), before that element has been created inside 'addNotice'. 
I've moved around some of the javascript...

And as @Jordan rightly noted, you need to change $(this). I'm just using `$("#growl .notice")` for this now

Comment: Thank a lot , this is great,it works fine at JSFIDDLE , but  when i put it in my html , i have this error  Unexpected token ILLEGAL at the the end.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit
or just Google 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL' ;)

Comment: Sorry my bad, Thanks Everything is Working Perfect Thank u very very much.

Answer (score 4):

The this in your click function callback no longer refers to the calling object so you need to bind the this context of the calling object to that function, or change this to the id of the element you want to close.