# Trying to transfer Tributary D3.js example into JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm rather a beginner at both JS and D3.js; [my JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/considerphlebas/py3eaLg9/).

JSHint shows no errors, so I think I'm doing the D3 wrong.

I'm trying to do the same thing as in these questions, adapting a Tributary example to run outside of that platform: ["Exporting" a Tributary example that makes use of the tributary object - d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530584/exporting-a-tributary-example-that-makes-use-of-the-tributary-object-d3-js) and [Getting horizontal stack bar example to display using d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691805/getting-horizontal-stack-bar-example-to-display-using-d3-js) (I'm even adapting the same code as the latter) Unfortunately, there is no corrected JSFiddle or other example in either answer

Here's my code:

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() { 
var margins = {
    top: 12,
    left: 48,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 24
};
var data = [
{"key":"Nonviolent", "cat1":0.69, "cat2":0.21, "cat3":0.10},
{"key":"Violent", "cat1":0.53, "cat2":0.29, "cat3":0.18}
];

var catnames = {cat1: "No mental illness",
                cat2: "Mild mental illness",
                cat3: "Moderate or severe mental illness"}; 

var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
        .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');

var n = 3, // number of layers
    m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
    stack = d3.layout.stack(),
    labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

    //go through each layer (cat1, cat2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
    //then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's catulation data
    //and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
    layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
                var a = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                     a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['cat' + (d+1)]};  
                }
                return a;
             })),

    //the largest single layer
    yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
    //the largest stack
    yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangeRoundBands([2, height], 0.08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yStackMax])
    .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickPadding(6)
    .tickValues(labels)
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing a (); at the end of your function and before the semicolon. That would make it self executing. I forked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slove/72L2v18n/1/).

```
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() { 
var margins = {
    top: 12,
    left: 48,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 24
};
var data = [
{"key":"Nonviolent", "cat1":0.69, "cat2":0.21, "cat3":0.10},
{"key":"Violent", "cat1":0.53, "cat2":0.29, "cat3":0.18}
];

var catnames = {cat1: "No mental illness",
                cat2: "Mild mental illness",
                cat3: "Moderate or severe mental illness"}; 

var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
        .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');

var n = 3, // number of layers
    m = data.length, // number of samples per layer
    stack = d3.layout.stack(),
    labels = data.map(function(d) {return d.key;}),

    //go through each layer (cat1, cat2 etc, that's the range(n) part)
    //then go through each object in data and pull out that objects's catulation data
    //and put it into an array where x is the index and y is the number
    layers = stack(d3.range(n).map(function(d) { 
                var a = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                     a[i] = {x: i, y: data[i]['cat' + (d+1)]};  
                }
                return a;
             })),

    //the largest single layer
    yGroupMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y; }); }),
    //the largest stack
    yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function(layer) { return d3.max(layer, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });

var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 677 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 533 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangeRoundBands([2, height], 0.08);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yStackMax])
    .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range(["#aad", "#556"]);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.x); })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y); });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickPadding(6)
    .tickValues(labels)
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

}();
```

Comment: I... feel pretty dumb. Thank you!