# How to assigning an HTML string to a variable in JavaScript with easily escaping from special characters

Tags: javascript, escaping

I want to assign an HTML string to a JavaScript variable but it gives error because of special characters. Is there any easy way to escape that characters?

What I want to do at my js file:

```
var messageTemplate = {
   defaultMessageTemplate : "<p>aaaa <b>_username_</b>,</p>
            <p>1sdfasşlğllğlğ.</p>
            <p><b>1 sdfsfsfü şesdfce 12 sfsf.</b></p>
            <p>Üsdfdsfsfsf üyelesfdsdfsdfmsdfdsfdava.</p>
            <p style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 16px;"><a href="/dsfsfs">sfsdfsf Yarasfsdfklayın</a></p>
        <p>Önsdfdsfpıİsdfdfsfn kaçırmayın.</p>
        <br/> <br/>fafaf, <br/>_domain_ Ekssibi</textarea></label></td>"
.... code continues here
};
```

Comment: What are those special characters?

Comment: And how do you assign those characters and what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` inside the string quoted with `"` using `\"`:

```
var messageTemplate = {
   defaultMessageTemplate : "<p>aaaa <b>_username_</b>,</p>
            <p>1sdfasşlğllğlğ.</p>
            <p><b>1 sdfsfsfü şesdfce 12 sfsf.</b></p>
            <p>Üsdfdsfsfsf üyelesfdsdfsdfmsdfdsfdava.</p>
            <p style=\"font-weight:bold; font-size: 16px;\"><a href=\"/dsfsfs\">sfsdfsf Yarasfsdfklayın</a></p>
        <p>Önsdfdsfpıİsdfdfsfn kaçırmayın.</p>
        <br/> <br/>fafaf, <br/>_domain_ Ekssibi</textarea></label></td>"
};
```

Or use single quotes where you can use `"` without escaping them (but you would need to escape `'`):

```
var messageTemplate = {
   defaultMessageTemplate : '…'
};
```

And if this JavaScript code is embedded into HTML, you also [need to escape the `</` somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write).

Comment: I escaped <p> as \<p> and didn't escaped </p> so it looks like works. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: @kamaci: No, you need to “remove” the literal `</` somehow and that only when embedding it into HTML as that’s interpreted as end tag open delimiter of the `SCRIPT` element.

Answer (score 2):

use the escape function:
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/escape.html

but be warned that this escapes everything.  It depends on what you want to do with that html in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`escape`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions) function or the newer [**`encodeURIComponent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: `escape` is not a standard function.

Comment: @Gumbo true, but all major browsers support it. That said I agree and recommend `encodeURIComponent` if it is available on the target browsers.