# Using JavaScript in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have two javascript files and one html page. i want to include a js file to another js file but i dont know how to include js file to another one.

anyone can please help me?

following is my code

html code:

```
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <script src="main.js" ></script>

   </head>
   <body onload="show()">
   </body> </head>
   </html>
```

following are the javascript files:

1.js

```
  var x=10;
  function show()
  {
     setvalue(x)
   }
```

2.js

```
   var D=;
   function setvalue(x)
   {
     D = x;
     alert(D);
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809862/can-we-call-the-function-written-in-one-javascript-in-another-js-file

Comment: @MukulGoel duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892845/how-to-load-one-javascript-file-from-another. you have your answer in the lnik i provided.

Comment: 2.js isn't valid, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @Walfrat: My answer? I didnt ask the question. Thanks for adding the link though. That should be helpful for OP.

Answer (score -1):

if it's just a matter of accessing the functions and objects in the first javascript file just do something like this:
    `<script src="main1.js"></script>`
    `<script src="main2.js"></script>`

this way any function in main1.js will be available in main2.js