# How to access Sphinx-generated search index through static JavaScript files?

Tags: python-sphinx

When Sphinx generates documentation, it also generates special `searchindex.js` file, which contains all of the documentation items. How to acess it from a JS script placed in _static?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `_static/myfile.js`, you can reference the path from the root of the built docs, for example, `/searchindex.js`.

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I'm coming from NodeJS and not very familiar with web technologies sadly..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892845/how-to-load-one-javascript-file-from-another