# How to pass jQuery to eval'd code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

First, check out my [fiddle fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcSYz/)

jsFiddle is nice, but sometimes it runs a bit slow, so I made this simple pure JS fiddle (can be ran locally)

Working great so far, but I want to be able to use jQuery in my fiddle. Type `alert(typeof $);` in the bottom left box and press "Run" to see what I mean (says undefined).

So how do I pass jQuery off to the iframe and give it the correct context? I suspect I could set `doc.contentWindow.$=$` or something like that, but I still need to give the correct context so it knows where to find the elements. How would I do that?

---

```
iframe.contentWindow.$ = $.proxy($,iframe.contentWindow);
```

That didn't work either. Gives me access to jQuery, but the context is still wrong.

---

```
iframe.contentWindow.$ = function(s){return $(s,doc);};
```

That sort of works... but it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Why not embed it inside using a `<script>` statement pointing to the Google CDN?

Comment: You made a fiddle in a fiddle?!  That's meta.

Comment: This may be too Meta for me, I'm not sure I get it correctly. :)

Comment: @Pekka: But is it really too meta? http://min.us/lbw1Ce3eY2l4hb (i couldn't get it to go down another level :(

Comment: @Mark no, it was just too Meta for *me*, I was at the end of a very exhaustiv work day :)

Comment: @Pekka: there we go... http://i.minus.com/ib0Yf8w8UT8VML.png got it to go a couple levels deeper thanks to John and gilly! the button got in my way of going any further :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do as jsfiddle itself does? It simply includes a script tag for jQuery (or whatever framework you asked for) in the `head` of the `iframe`.

If you look in `head` of the... uh "outer" `iframe` (the one jsfiddle created), you'll see they just threw this in there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
```

Same thing applies to the "on ready" and "on load" options, jsfiddle just wraps the appropriate call around your javascript before injecting it into the iframe.

Modifying your code a little, you can create a `script` element:

```
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var jqueryTag = doc.createElement('script');
jqueryTag.type = 'text/javascript';
jqueryTag.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js';
```

and then append that element to the `head`.

Comment: I keep getting a syntax error when I try doing that (http://jsfiddle.net/XcSYz/1/) not sure why... my IDE (gedit) looks like it terminates the string as soon as I type the `>` in `</script>`, as though it's trying to close the actual `<script>` outside the string.

Comment: Browsers will see the `</script>` in your string and end the script block in the middle of things, you need to re-jigger a little: `\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js">\x3C/script>`.  [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write).

Comment: Thought so! Thanks. That got rid of the JS error, but jQuery still isn't accessible.

Comment: I had better luck when using `createElement` (also happily avoids the script closing tag business): [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNYf4/3/) (that also addresses some other weirdness you had where you were appending everything to the `body`).

Comment: Nice! That fixed it up. I think this tool should be pretty handy now...lovin' the live preview :D

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your fiddle fiddle a little: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/XcSYz/3/

First, you can't write a doctype to the body's innerHTML and expect it to do anything for you.  Same with a charset meta tag.  I moved all of that to a `document.write` call.

You were evaluating script tags oninput of the editors.  First this throws errors like crazy if you are editing a script tag in the html frame.  Second, if you put an `alert("hello")` in a script tag in the HTML pane, then with every keypress, you get an alert.  Third, you were evaluating the scripts in the context of the parent window.  I changed html script tags to be evaluated when run is clicked and with the correct context.

Since you don't want to re-write the document every time (you can't, eg doctype), I modified it slightly to do some dom manipulation instead.  It removes and replaces the style tag and writes only the HTML pane contents to the body's innerHTML.

This is a fun little project you are trying.  jsFiddle is buggy and needs some updates.  I don't know how viable your pure client-side fiddle is - jsFiddle is quite robust (despite its bugs), but it is a nice exercise to give your approach a try.

**Edit:** One more change included in [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/XcSYz/7/):  I modified your textareas to use `width: 50%; height: 50%;` instead of setting `right` and `bottom`.  Those weren't working properly in IE or FF.

Comment: 1st paragraph: oops. didn't think that one through. 2nd: yes, i realized the same thing which is why i added the "run" button, but then i forgot to remove the old code. i might have a checkbox though to have it continuously run when you're editing the html. thanks for the tips/help! i might try seeing how they did the syntax highlighting and indentation later.

Comment: why are you removing the `<style>` though? can't we just replace its contents? (wouldn't that be more efficient?)

Comment: @Mark - I didn't think you could replace the "html" of a style tag at runtime, but tried and sure enough, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/XcSYz/7/.  I was being cautious, trying to prevent old styles from sticking around, but it looks like either way works.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement on the "fiddle fiddle", but I'm not sure it answers the question (other than in the code of the linked fiddle, that is).

Comment: @JohnFlatness: True that. I liked this solution better so I gave him the check, but I guess you're still the one that solved the problem :) You can have it back!

Comment: @gilly3: Ah..good to know. I was only testing in Chrome so far. The borders seem to be gone with your new version though. Oh wow...it really does look awful in Firefox (the old one)

Comment: I really wish you could do 50% minus 1 px. I think the other div is covering up the border. Oh maybe if I set a z-index... (talking to self) **edit:** yup...that actually worked. http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/XcSYz/8/