# why browser can not parse the following code?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function cool()
    {
        var innerHtml = "<script></script>";//simply for demostration
        $("body").append(innerHtml);
    }
 </script>
```

The above will confuse browsers and will not render correctly before the cool function is even invoked. Why?

Comment: Because browsers will choke on the `</script>` inside the JavaScript string, The HTML parser does not understand JavaScript, and will only see this token and will close the script block.

Comment: It's quite confusing as to what you're doing here. Can you please explain your problem more clearly, with more detail?

Comment: Do you want the `<script>` tags to appear as text or execute?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: @JamWaffles What other details are needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`</script>` [will end a script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#idx-CDATA-1), so your script terminates in the middle of a string literal.

Browsers are not "confused", the HTML is simply wrong (and invalid … except in XHTML … but that only counts if you are using application/xhtml+xml … and then you get a different set of issues), which leads to the JavaScript being wrong.

Represent the sequence `</` as `<\/` in JS strings when you are using inline JS (as per the [example in section 18.2.4 of the HTML 4.01 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#idx-document)).