# appending jQuery Library with document.write : IE get frozen?

Tags: jquery, html, popup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5quVz/2/) code on my page :

```
var print_popup = window.open("", "Booking", "width=950,height=680, scrollbars=1");

print_popup.document.write("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");

print_popup.document.write("<head>");
print_popup.document.write("<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>");
print_popup.document.write("</head>");

print_popup.document.write("<body>");
print_popup.document.write("<div class='element'>Hello</div>");
print_popup.document.write("<div class='element2'>Marco</div>");
print_popup.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>$('.element').hide();</script>");
print_popup.document.write("</body>");
print_popup.document.write("</html>");

print_popup.document.close();
```

So, when I open the popup, I insert the jquery Library. Than, I'd like to hide `element`.
On Firefox/Chrome there are no problems; on IE (8) the browser open a about-blank popup, and the window get frozen (I need to force-close the browser).

I know I should hide the element with CSS, but for other operations I need jQuery.

Why this? And how can I fix it?

## EDIT

Tried replacing `<` with `\x3` but still the problem. It seems to crash appending just the jQuery Library...

Comment: Have a read of this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: Tried with escape : I see `downloading date <script src='jquery...` in the bottom of the page...

Comment: -1 for your problem description consisting of, in totality, "it crash".

Comment: Edited the whole question! Is it more clear right now?

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap `$('.element').hide();` into `$(function(){$('.element').hide();});`