# Dynamically insert javascript using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I am trying to dynamically insert a set of script tags with some javascript code in it using javascript. I am basically trying to wrap a file in jwplayer, but the script string is breaking rest of the javascript code in the page. How do I do this correctly?

the line causing the problem:

```
        $file_link_insert = "<script   type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({flashplayer: 'player.swf', file: '"+$href+"'});</script>";
```

Rest of function for ref:

```
$(".file_link").live("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $href = $(this).attr("rel");
                // Dialog           
                $('#filelink').dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 300,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Ok": function() {
                            if($("input[name=file_link_text]").val()!=""){

                                $file_type = fileType($href);//determine if its video file see function below.

                                if($file_type == 'vid'){

                                   $file_link_insert = "<script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({flashplayer: 'player.swf', file: '"+$href+"'});</script>";

                                  // $file_link_insert = " <p><a href=\""+$href+"\">"+$("input[name=file_link_text]").val()+"</a></p> ";

                                }else { $file_link_insert = " <p><a href=\""+$href+"\">"+$("input[name=file_link_text]").val()+"</a></p> "; }

                                $("#_tinyMCEinit_ifr").contents().find("body").append($file_link_insert);
                                $("#content_editor ul li:first a").click();
                                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                                $("input[name=file_link_text]").val("");
                                } else { alert("You must enter text label for your link!"); }
                            },
                        "Cancel": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                            }
                        }
                }); 
            });
```

Comment: Why don't you just call this line inside your if block ?

Comment: The problem is that the `</script>` actually ends the js prematurely.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of [jQuery: Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't include `</script>` within a javascript because the browser will interpret it as the end of the script. Simply break up or escape the string. like this `<\/script>`

See [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: [There’s no need to use string concatenation](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago); just use a simple JavaScript escape sequence and write `<\/script>`.

Comment: Yep, anything that's not `</script>`

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way is to use DOM and dynamically load Javascript and append it anywhere you wish:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "myScript.js";
$("head").append( script );
```

*Appended into head tag in this case, you can change the script.src to script.text for inline scripts.*

Comment: [Setting `script.type` is unnecessary.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet#type)

Comment: Maybe I want "application/javascript" or "text/jscript" or "text/ecmascript", we have 11 types for scripting! how to distinguish?

Comment: In those cases you would set the `.type`. But since `text/javascript` is what we’re after here, I don’t see how it adds any value.

Comment: I got it working simply by </scr"+"ipt> but now its failing to append on $("#_tinyMCEinit_ifr").contents().find("body").append($file_link_insert); its saying jwplayer is not defined Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$file_link_insert = "<script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({flashplayer: 'player.swf', file: '"+$href+"'});</script>";
```

[You need to escape `</script>` here or it will close the `<script>` element.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago) Use a simple [JavaScript escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes), e.g. `<\/script>`:

```
$file_link_insert = "<script>jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({flashplayer: 'player.swf', file: '"+$href+"'});<\/script>";
```

Comment: This works but now I have a new problem that jwplayer is not inserted into tincymce as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need create script tag through DOM API. 
document.createElement("script");