# Why "document.write('<scr'+"?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

I have only shallow knowledge of JavaScript, and was wondering why I often see the following type of code in web pages:

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="'+bub_url+'"><'+'/script>');
```

What not just write...

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+bub_url+'"></script>');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write