# javascript not functioning on firefox

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

There is supposed to be an American Apparel advertisement on my site, in the right hand side bar, in between the headers "Bloglovin" and "Twitter". It seems to function fine on the iphone/ipad, but it doesnt show up on my computer in Firefox or Safari. If anyone could help me as to why this is, it would be much appreciated.

http://www.lookbookcookbook.com/

I am using the following code

```
<!-- JavaScript for Static HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var mpt = new Date();
var mpts = mpt.getTimezoneOffset() + mpt.getTime();
document.write("<scri" + "pt type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/altfarm.mediaplex.com\/ad\/js\/8975-64333-44152-3\?mpt=" + mpts + "&mpvc=\"><\/scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
 <noscript>
<a href="http://altfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nc/8975-64333-44152-3">
<img src="http://altfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/nb/8975-64333-44152-3" 
alt="Click Here" border="0" />
</a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write  Using `document.write()` to create a script tag requires special tricks.

Comment: i dont really know what im doing, so could that be explained maybe?

Comment: Instead of `document.write("<script>....</script>")` you need to break up the `<script>` strings to prevent them being interpreted as closing tags.  Use `document.write("<script type=.....>.....</scr" + "ipt>");`  Examine how it is done in the code example in the linked question.

Comment: @Rocket I think you're correct.

Comment: @Michael: Also, that question says that `<\/script>` should also be a valid solution.  http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago

Comment: working for me in firefox and chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using CloudFlare's [Rocket Script](http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Rocket_Script), which means you can't use `document.write` (you shouldn't use `document.write` anyway).

You need to use `document.createElement` instead.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://altfarm.mediaplex.com/ad/js/8975-64333-44152-3?mpt=" + mpts + "&mpvc=";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

EDIT: Their script also contains a `document.write`.  You can't actually use this ad on your page, unless you turn "Rocket Script" off.

Comment: Thank you! I still cant get it working, could you show me where to substitute this new code in the one I already have?

Comment: @user1253957: Replace `document.write(...` with these lines.

Comment: @user1253957: Their code contains `document.write`.  You can't use this ad code along with "Rocket Loader".