# Javascript: Funny string concatenation for script tag

Tags: javascript, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Browsing through some [Chromium source](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/http/tests/security/resources/libwrapjs.js) (see line 45ff), I found:

```
in_script_tag: function(code) {
  return "<script>" + code + "</scr" + "ipt>";
},
```

Does anyone know why the author chose `"</scr" + "ipt>"` over `"</script>"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a `<script>` tag `</script>` ends it, no matter where it occurs.

**Example:**

```
<script>
alert('</script>');
// anything here will not be executed anymore
</script>
```

The reason for this is simply that the browser does not know anything about JavaScript strings etc. so when it sees `</script>` it always closes the `<script>` tag.

Comment: As a mod candidate, would you delete this question as it's a duplicate of a famous question?

Comment: No, vote-to-close is sufficient. That's a case where I'll leave it to the community if they want to delete it or not.

Comment: And what is your personal stand?

Comment: There's no need to delete it. While the title is not the best one the question is properly asked, has good answers and thus has some value. Besides that, I think it's much more important to delete *bad* content than *duplicate* content.

Answer (score 1):

Because each time HTML parser sees the `</script`, it automatically considers the javascript fragment finished. )

Comment: That's not the JavaScript parser but the HTML parser.

Comment: If you can reproduce that bug, report it on [meta]

Comment: Actually it was described on Meta several times; just the first time I faced it. So I suppose it's not such a big deal.