# Insert code snippet to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used Jquery to insert a variable to div. Please check my code.

```
var msg = '<script src="https://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb"></script>'
$('.result').html(msg);
```

msg variable contains a script that render a code snippet. msg is dynamic variable.

The above code is not working to insert code snippet to div.

Any Idea?

This script generate code snippet like this.

[image]

Comment: How are you calling the code? Document ready?

Comment: why are u adding `script` inside `div`???

Comment: What is your purpose, execute a script or just display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `script`, I would add it to `head` like this;

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb';
s.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Not in this case. Adding a script to the head that outputs display code won't work, will it?

Comment: @BryanH: I know, just posted a common approach. Though in that case `document.getElementById('id')` would do that trick :)

Comment: `var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb";
    script.type = "text/javascript";  document.getElementById('aaa').appendChild(script);`. This code inserted script. but not render any code snippet.

Comment: @Shamithc: Since it is dynamically added, it will not be visible when you view Souce Code option from browser.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: There is no element with `result` as tag name in html :)

Comment: @Blaster yeh you are right, i updated. its better to include this in head tag

Comment: Change `getElementsByID` to `getElementById` :)

Comment: Since the OP is using jQuery, why not stick with it? jQuery's selectors are much easier (and safer) than `getElementById`.

Comment: @BryanH its easy, agreed. But how u can say that its more safer?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a github gist into a page dynamically using that embed code.  The embed code is fine if you can add the script tag to the HTML, but to do it dynamically via JavaScript as you are trying to do, it won't work because it relies on `document.write()`.

Instead, use the [github gists api](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/):

```
$.get("https://api.github.com/gists/3010234", function(response) {
    $(".result").text(response.data.files["new.html.erb"].content);
}, "jsonp");
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/naTqe/

Comment: As seen in [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write/236106#236106).

Comment: `$.getScript("https://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb");
` is working. But I am not able to render code snippet generated by script into the div.

Comment: @Shamithc - The script your are trying to load uses `document.write()`, which you shouldn't use after the document has finished loading.

Comment: @Shamithc - I've abandoned [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11338983/2), because, while technically accurate, it addresses a red herring and gets you no closer to accomplishing your *actual* goal of loading a github gist into a page dynamically using JavaScript.  See my new answer above for a workable solution.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. But I missed gist styling, I need to generate code from that script itself. You are tried to get content only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your remote JS is buggy. I ran it through [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) and came up with several errors.

Anyway, here is my working example. Keep a javascript console open and you'll see the error when it tries to parse the remote JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Jquery test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>jQuery</h1>

  <p class="result">Some result</p>
  <script>
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var msg = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gist.github.com/3010234.js?file=new.html.erb"><\/script>";
  $('.result').html(msg);
  });
  /*]]>*/
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```