# Including a script with innerHTML - escaping characters

Tags: javascript, escaping, innerhtml

I'm trying to output a `<script>` element in an innerHTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fileManager()
    {
        data = document.getElementById("FM");
        data.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='functions.js'></script>";
    }
</script>
    <div id="FM"></div>
    <ul id="show-menu">
        <li onClick="fileManager()">File Manager
    </ul>
```

The innerHTML bit of the script works perfectly, it's just that there's a problem with escaping characters inside the double quotes ("). The whole `<script type='text/javascript' src='functions.js'></script>` seems to be broken/written incorrectly and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it.

In case you're wondering, the functions.js file contains only `document.write("test");` for testing purposes.

For some unknown reason this does not work. The result is a broken page, I see bits of other functions in the script and it doesn't make sense. How do I escape it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The literal `<script>`/`</script>` inside the script is actually breaking the html tag that contains the script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write). There is also the problem that
`.innerHTML` [does not execute or load scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0). So I suggest:

```
function fileManager()
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = 'functions.js';
    document.getElementById("FM").appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this code. But the innerHTML isn't supposed to execute a script. It's purpose is to put the <script> tag inside a <div> element as plain text. Later on, the browser should do whatever the <script> tag does, since it detects it as an HTML element. At least that was the idea. I've read somewhere that this is supposed to actually work, it's just outputting an HTML tag inside a <div>

Comment: @user1020567 I don't understand, you either want the script to execute or you don't. But it seems you want to it both, to execute and not execute? Script elements created with `.innerHTML` will not execute so I don't understand. And the whole purpose of creating a script element is to execute its `src` or its contents, which you cannot do with `.innerHTML`. Man am I confused now :D

Comment: That's not what I meant. innerHTML will put anything I write within double quotes into the <div> element. Theoretically, it should be possible to pass on the <script> element, since it's just simple HTML. The browser will execute the script as soon as it's inside that <div>

Comment: @user1020567 the browser will not execute scripts that you create with `.innerHTML`. And if it doesn't work, please see if there are any errors. Also, replace `document.write` with `console.log` :p

Comment: But aren't the scripts "created" with innerHTML just a simple HTML code output inside a <div> element? I mean, it's practically the same as outputting some html inside a document.write - the document.write itself doesn't execute that html code, it just places it on the page so that the browser can actually interpret it.

Comment: @user1020567 scripts created with `document.write` are loaded and executed, I said that scripts created with `.innerHTML` are not. It is stated in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0): *script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.*

Comment: Also, if your functions.js script uses document.write then an async load like this will blank out your page since it'll probably load up after the DOM is ready. If that's the case and you are unable to modify your functions.js - you might have to go for a document.write over ride. Is your page coming up blank with this code ?

Comment: Alright, I can see that you don't fully understand what I meant. Lets say we do this: data.innerHTML = "<img src='img.jpg'>" <-- this will result in the img.jpg image being displayed inside that <div> element, right? So why not any other HTML element in the world such as <script>? What are the limitations? EDIT: I've just noticed your new comment. Oh well. Thanks for the help, I'll try to fix the syntax errors.

Comment: @user1020567 the limitations are that script elements are not executed and invalid html is usually handled "unexpectedly"

Comment: I've just re-checked the code and it still doesn't work. I literally copy-pasted your code and replaced my own function with it, but nothing happens when I invoke the fileManager() function.

Comment: @user1020567 did you check the network tab if the script is being loaded? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, the script IS being loaded and the console outputs the text successfully

Comment: @user1020567 then what is the problem?

Comment: When I invoke the function fileManager() the <div> element is not changed. The network tab shows that the script is loaded successfully but the console.log("text") simply doesn't output any text. In the Console tab I can see that the text "text" is being output, but that doesn't happen within the page

Comment: @user1020567 yes, `console.log` prints in the console not on the page. If you want to do something with the page, then you can use methods like `.innerHTML` etc. If the text is logged, then the script was loaded and is working properly. Script tags are not printed on the page. You can [inspect element](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) on the div to see it has a `script` child though.

Comment: Well that was the idea, I wanted to use innerHTML to change the contents of the <div> element with an external script (which initially included document.write("text")

Comment: @user1020567 in the `functions.js` file , write `document.getElementById("FM").innerHTML = "text";` instead of `console.log`

Comment: I already did that and was surprised it that it doesn't work :/ EDIT: I've restarted the browser and it works now. It appears that the browser had cached an old version of the page and it needed a restart.

Comment: @user1020567 are you sure you are not using a cached file? If the script loads and executes without errors, there are probably not many other explanations :D

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything works now! (check the edit on the comment above)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in certain browsers that will mess up when you try to insert script tags using javascript. What you need to do is break up the script tags like this:

```
"<scr"+"ipt..........</scr"+"ipt>"
```

This will work.

Comment: Does this actually make a difference?

Comment: @climbage It does for me when dealing with firefox and certain doc types.

Comment: @AshrayBaruah I'm genuinely curious how this changes anything.  It seems like the resulting string would just be... the same thing without splitting up.

Comment: @climbage yes from the point of view of javascript but not from the point of view of html

Comment: @climbage Alright, here is a pretty good discussion on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: @AshrayBaruah Ahhh, now I understand where the splitting makes a difference.  Thanks for the extra info