# Why is the script tag broken up in to two strings?

Tags: javascript, optimization, enyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Looking at the enyo source, I see this (in enyo.js):

```
document.write('<scri' + 'pt src="' + root + "/source/boot/" + inSrc + '"></scri' + 'pt>');
```

Why is the `<script` tag broken into `<scri + pt` ? The same is done for the end tag. Is this a secret of the Javascript ninja that I'm not aware of?

Comment: this has nothing to do with `document.write`. you must split the CLOSING script tag anywhere you want it as a javascript string; splitting the opening script tag is not necessary.

Comment: `<\/script>` and then life is good again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a browser's html parser sees the string "`</script>`", regardless of whether it is in a javascript string or not, it sees it as a closing script tag and ends the current script block. Breaking the "`</script>`" tag into two pieces prevents this from happening when you need it as a javascript string.

See [this explanation](http://www.wwco.com/%7Ewls/blog/2007/04/25/using-script-in-a-javascript-literal/):

> the  tag is content-agnostic. Which means the HTML Parser
> doesn’t know we’re in the middle of a JavaScript string.
>
> The processing of JavaScript doesn’t happen until after the browser
> has understood which parts are JavaScript. Until it sees that close
>  tag, it doesn’t care what’s inside – quoted or not.

Answer (score 0):

it is designed to get the script tag around various filters.

Answer (score 0):

This is necessary because the parser considers that substring as the closing `<script>` tag in which the statement itself is contained, so it's necessary make a split somewhere in the middle

Answer (score 0):

To prevent browsers from blocking the `document.write`. It's usually unsafe to do things of this sort.

Also, for old browsers which when seeing `</script>` anywhere in the body, would stop execution right away. Which meant anything after the `document.write` wouldn't be considered JavaScript code.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/VuC3M/) to see what I mean. The `script` tag closes right after the alert.

Comment: This is a pretty standard way to implement JSONP. Google does it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @TravisWebb I've added a demo to the answer to show you what I mean.