# How do I escape a semicolon inside of a String?

Tags: java, javascript, string, escaping

I need to initialize complex javascript code as an string. But that javascript code contains semicolon and " mark. I know I can escape " mark using \". But I don't know how to escape semicolon.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "8888888888888";
/* Error Page Ads */
google_ad_slot = "8888888";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I need to initialize above code as,

```
String complexString = "Above code here";
```

I can't concatenate slices of code, because that way ; will be removed. Right?

This is for Servlet. I may be foolish, but pardon me.

Comment: Semicolons in string literals are meaningless...What are you getting at here?

Comment: You don't need to escape semicolons

Comment: What problem are you getting.. Semi-colon will not trouble you.. Get going..

Comment: Are you getting an error message or seeing the code getting cut off somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I thought java mix up with semicolon that ends an statement. As long as semicolon inside "" marks it not trouble. Thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is non-constructive.  It's a valid question.  Just because it's misguided or has an obvious (to most of us) answer, doesn't mean it's non-constructive.

Comment: For everyone that is questioning the motives, if you try to export data into a CSV that is going to be separed by semicolon, if they are unescaped it will break the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is escape the quote characters in your javascript not your semicolon characters.

So ultimately you would want

```
String complexString = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--
google_ad_client = \"8888888888888\";
/* Error Page Ads */
google_ad_slot = \"8888888\";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script>  
<script type=\"text/javascript\"
src=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\">  
</script>"
```

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Answer (score 4):

As long as the `;` is inside your double quotes you shouldn't need to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

Semicolons are not special characters. There's no need of escaping them when they're in a `String`. You can always test a string's behavior by using the little old `System.out.println()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape your `;` when they are inside `"` or `'`, as they are literals and are perfectly safe.

Comment: I am not going to downvote, but semicolons and commas are commonly used in CSV exports and will break the file if unescaped. That is a good reason to escape them.

Comment: @sfratini Thanks, I'll try amending the answer.  Happy to take in advice.