# Why does Google split the <script> tag in their document.write() call?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

The Google DFP mobile init code contains this:

`document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + src + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');`

How is this any better than doing:

`document.write('<script src="' + src + '"></script>');`

Comment: Anti-scraping measures, presumably. `<script` is easy enough to find in a page for a bot, but not so much `<scr' + 'ipt`.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the face that some CMS's MAY filter anything that starts with <script. This may just be a simple workaround. Unsure though!

Answer (score 1):

In some cases where Javascript is processed or handled -- for example when the code is embedded into an HTML page -- the character sequences `</script` and `<script` are processed separately, *before* the Javascript is parsed to identify string constants and the like.

Therefore it is more robust to make sure that Javascript code one writes *never* contains these character sequences. It is arguably a good defensive habit to do this even for code that is not *currently* being processed by systems that would be broken by `</script>` -- because that will prevent problems in case the code is later copy-pasted into a context where `</script>` does produce a problem.