# How should we prevent XSS attacks that *only* break page rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, json, xss

Suppose we have a form that allows entering a piece of markdown as a message body. That text is then render in HTML as *JSON* on another page:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       loadMessage({
           name: 'John Doe',
           message: '**Hello** World'
       });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Pretend that `loadMessage` uses a markdown parser (e.g. [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)) and outputs the HTML at runtime.

I've identified a case where a malicious user could cause an error on the page:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       loadMessage({
           name: 'John Doe',
           message: '</script>'
       });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Because `</script>` causes the browser to close the script block, an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` exception is thrown. Marked is able to sanitize such an attack, but this attack is even before JavaScript execution.

1. Strip all `<script>` and `</script>` when the initial form is submitted. This would mean updating a lot of our framework code (using ASP.NET MVC - so we'd have to extend the default ModelBinder).
2. Leverage the JSON formatter for this - convert to `'</' + 'script>'` when writing the JSON. We'd be keeping the source intact - but maybe that's *a bad thing*.

How should we mitigate such an attack?

Comment: Why don't you escape the HTML entities?

Comment: It's markdown and markdown [allows HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). Is it really worth it to escape and then unescape on the client?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're outputting the Markdown into the JavaScript and not directly into the HTML?

Comment: Yes - we bootstrap our models/views on the client to get access to raw data. We're using Backbone and this is a [common thing to do](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) with Backbone applications.

Comment: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/12/19/aspnet-mvc-prevent-xss-with-automatic-html-encoding/

Comment: @DaveA - That's unrelated to this. That's encoding when the page is rendered as HTML *not* as JSON.

Comment: Clearly I miss the distinction. I assume this won't be an issue until it is *rendered*. So from that perspective, I assume issues with a **client-side tag** don't matter on way in. Only on *render*. If not, please clarify what I'm overlooking...

Comment: @Dave - You're correct.

Comment: Ok, then i would guess any values rendered using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value)` should be protected from XSS.

Comment: @DaveA - But they *do* matter when rendered in the HTML. The markdown is parsed later on. The issue is purely with the JSON string.

Comment: When you feed yhe JSON string, can that be done with encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might personally go along with stripping anything resembling the script tag, as such an approach would provide an extra layer of security against validation bugs in your Markdown parser. But your mileage may vary depending on your application.

If you do need to encode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/131903 for a reasonable encoding approach (that is, use \x3c to replace the less-than sign). This will work:

```
<html>
  <script>
    alert("1 \x3c/script> 2");
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you strip the value when the form is posted or when the JSON is rendered?

Comment: A fair question. It is safer to strip on input, but you lose data permanently. But that way you don't have to strip on every output, and since it is unlikely that script tags would be important data for you, I'd pick the safer route (after adding sufficient unit tests to ensure that my stripper actually works properly).

Comment: Yeah - I'm going to go with stripping on input. Cheers!