# closing script tag and document.write gets flagged in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1, ASP.NET and JavaScript

I'm trying to do a quick `document.write` test but as soon as I add script tags Visual Studio editor doesn't like it. Specifically, the closing script tag? I get those squiggly lines as soon as I enter the closing `</script>` tag

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.write('<html><head><script></script></head><body></body></html>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
document.write('<html><head><script><\/script></head><body></body></html>');
Note the `\`, here ------------------^
```

Another option is to split the string, so that it's not a exact tag:

```
document.write('<html><head><script></sc' + 'ript></head><body></body></html>');
```

Here's a reference explaining why it's needed, and other options:

- [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Anyways, why are you writing a whole document into the `<body>`?

Comment: not production stuff...just testing. Thanks. Why doesn't the other closing tags need it?

Comment: Well, I think it's because that string/code is currently inside of a `<script>` element, so the HTML parser is looking for the closing of it (not another element)

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Visual Studio, but I can tell that there are some errors on your HTML architecture, You shouldn't re-insert `<html><head><body>` if it is already in the HTML document, also try to escape the slash:

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.write('<script>alert("hello");<\/script>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If alert hello works then you are in the good track