# getJSON troubles with some symbols

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

getJSON troubles with some symbols in url

When i try this:

```
var lics='<?php header("Content-Type:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8","Refresh:0;url=http://example.com/");$arr=array("k"=>array("'+nme+
'"=>array("u"=>"'+gva('PrimaryKey')+'","d"=>"'+gva('SecondKey')+'")));echo $_GET["cb"]."(".json_encode($arr).");";?>',

call=[plist+'&dir=conf&nme='+nme+'.plist&arg=wb',
    lics+'&dir=.lic&nme='+nme+'.lics.php&arg=wb',
    init+'&dir=../&nme=init.'+nme+'.js&arg=wb]',

cjsn=function(c){
  $(c).each(function(i){
    $.getJSON(loc+'/.bin/.utl/com.mkupdate.php?cb=&bin='+c[i] )
    .done(function(){
      if(c===cdel){alert(help[17]);alert(help[18]);
      location.replace('http://'+location.host);
      }
    })
    .fail(function(){fail(i);});
  });
};
cjsn(call);
```

callback doesn't work, but when i delete "<" or ">" symbol from "lics" or letter "t" from "javascript", this callback works. How it resolve?

Comment: **What does the error say**? Where does it come from?

Comment: short answer - the interpreter stops when it encounters `</script>`, regardless of whether it is in a string or not. possible duplicate of [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: @SLaks This request is not sent, and `.fail()` activates

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: Are you using any kind of XSS protection where ever you are using this?

Comment: @ars265 no any protection

Comment: @Aleksov I don't think this is the issue but why do you have a second question mark in the query? An can you post the error you are having as shown in your javascript console?

Comment: @ars265 there are no errors in the console, a simple request is not working

Comment: What do you see in the **network** tab?

Comment: @SLaks 403 error in console

Comment: @SLaks GET http://example.com/com.mkupdate.php?cb=jQuery20005069328628014773_1367354984399&bin=%3C?php%20header(%22Content-Type:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8%22,%22Refresh:0;url=http://example.com/%22);$arr=array(%22k%22=%3Earray(%22ptmedia%22=%3Earray(%22u%22=%3E%22%22,%22d%22=%3E%22%22)));echo%20$_GET[%22cb%22].%22(%22.json_encode($arr).%22);%22;?%3E&dir=.lic&nme=ptmedia.lics.php&arg=wb&_=1367354984400 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
t

Answer (score 1):

Use the structured form of `$.getJSON` so that the parameters will be URL-encoded properly:

```
$.getJSON('file.php', {
    cb: '?',
    bin: myvar
}, function(result) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the `<` to `%3C` and `>` to `%3E`. Here is a reference to the characters that need encoding, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) post for how to encode in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is sending an [HTTP 403  Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) response.
You need to fix the server-side code so that it doesn't do that.