# Getting IE to load a different js file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection

Trying to get a page to load a different js file if the browser is IE, but a different one if it is any other browser. I've corrupted this, but it won't work, does anyone have any ideas?

Any help is appreciated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ie = false;
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
ie = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(ie == false)
{ 
document.write ("<script src="js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript">")</script>;
} else {
    document.write ("<script src="js/ieskins.js" type="text/javascript">")</script>;
}
</script>
```

Comment: As [@Teemu noted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17125763/363701), IE10 doesn't support conditional comments. [@UmairP's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17125702/363701) is probably the best approach for targeting IE<10, rather than the code in your Question. 

But browser detection in general should be your last choice if all else fails. Try to code it an X-browser way, or use feature dectection.

Mind if I ask why you're doing this in the first place?

Comment: @ZachL Well, this is one of those very few situations, where `document.write()` can be used, let's not ruin the fun ; ). Anyway, the edited part of UmairP's answer really is the approach OP should use, I just pointed out, what makes OP's code not to work...

Comment: @ZachL I was using it to fix a rendering bug in the IE Canvas tag. I've just put a couple of clocks on a site I was building, but in IE it renders the lines far thinner than every other browser, so I fixed it with loading an IE specific javascript with thicker lines. Using CoolClock.

Comment: @JamesJ ah, I see. That *does* look all messed up in IE. You may consider, however, that future versions of IE may not have this same "bug" so this conditional logic may be setting yourself up for future problems. If I were you, I would probably just choose a different clock. CoolClock hasn't been updated in over 3 years (and that was just some fixes on top of the 2007 codebase. I'm sure there's something better out there that is better maintained and which doesn't require Hacks or Browser detection.

Comment: Well, not as easy to find such a clock as I thought, but I did find this one: http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/V2rFN/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your last script tag is a little jumbled, plus as Teemu mentioned, IE10 does not support conditional HTML comments.

If you really need to target IE, I would check the user agent for "MSIE":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ie = !(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")<0);
  if(ie == false) { 
    document.write ("<script src=\"js/moreskins.js\"></scr"+"ipt>");
  } else {
    document.write ("<script src=\"js/ieskins.js\"></scr"+"ipt>");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you Ben, did exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Teemu I couldn't get it to. Might have been me being thick about it lol sorry, this one just got exactly what I wanted in a simplified form.

Comment: Might want to remember that indexOf isn't supported in IE8 or earlier.

Comment: It's not supported for arrays but is for strings [even in earlier versions of IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Hi Ben, what is the <0 at the end there? Can I use that to check IE versions less than 9 maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional comments to load file in IE and ignore in other browsers.

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <script src="js/ieskins.js" type="text/javascript">
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
   <script src="js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript">
<![endif]>
```

Note: the else part (`<![if !IE]>`) which is not a comment. So for IE it is else part and for other browsers, it is nothing.

EDIT

you can also try the following instead of `document.write`

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = "js/moreskins.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Tried that Umair, but it won't pick up the first one in IE or its over-riding it with moreskins and I'm not sure why, its why I went for the coded approach

Comment: just thought of something: you _need_ an explicit closing `</script>` tag ALWAYS, otherwise they don't work. It's silly and seems unnessecary, but thats how it works. Perhaps thats why James's *conditional comment* approach didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the closing `script` tag. When using `document.write()` to add scripts, you need to cut end tag into pieces. Something like below (notice the fixed quoting and parenthesing too).

```
document.write('<script src="js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Script execution is stopped, when parser founds the first literal end tag, that's why you need to cut it in the argument.

Also notice, that IE10 doesn't support conditional comments, you should rather use feature detection instead of browser detection.

Comment: Do you have a reference on that "cut end tag into pieces" thing? I never heard about that (but I never use `document.write()`) ;-)

Comment: @ZachL Seems not to found at MDN nor MSDN, I'll work on this later, and will post a comment when I find a something.

Comment: @ZachL In meanwhile you can try it yourself, writing a script with `document.write()` really doesn't work with literal `</script>` in the argument.

Comment: Very true. And very interesting. I found this, which satisfied me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: apparently `document.write('<script src="js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');` works too (and you have an accidental `;` after `'ipt>`).

Comment: @ZachL Yep, I'm using that particular implementation, but I thought it would be too heavy to put it here... You're right with the semicolon, corrected the code : ). I assume I don't need to search a good explanation for this any more?

Comment: yup; I'm good, thanks!  A total tangent, but a fun distraction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd take a stab at writing some code too ;-)

```
<script>
(function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script"),
        is_ie = (/MSIE/gi.test(navigator.userAgent));
    script.src = (is_ie) ? 'js/ieskins.js' : 'js/moreskins.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using navigator.userAgent is better and simple. You code doesn't work in any else browser except IE,because only IE understand the mean of `<!--[if IE]>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ie = false;
    if(/MSIE/gi.test(navigator.userAgent)){
       ie = true;
    }
    if(ie == false)
    { 
    document.write ("<script src="js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript">")</script>;
    } else {
        document.write ("<script src="js/ieskins.js" type="text/javascript">")</script>;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it make a difference? In that conditional comment OP is changing a predefined variable value to `true` instead of `false`. No other browsers will do that. And you've included all errors from the OP's code too...

Comment: you could shorten that code a bit too: `var ie = (/MSIE/gi.test(navigator.userAgent));`

Comment: @reyunan Wellcome to Stackoverflow. Looks like you don't want to correct your answer. All erranous answers here are usually downvoted...