# javascript document.write loaded but not executed

Tags: javascript

I have this code which is driving me mad.

```
parent.document.write("<script type='application/javascript' scr='http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip'><\/script>");
```

this works and adds to the head section of the html document :

```
<script type='application/javascript' scr='http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip'></script>
```

But it does not execute.
The difference is when i paste it directly into the head of the html document without the parent.document.write it works AND executes :

```
    <script type='application/javascript' scr='http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip'></script>
```

gives output in firebug html source code :

```
<script src="http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip" type="application/javascript">
getip({"ip": "195.241.100.221"});
</script>
```

when loaded trough the parent.document.write function NO IP output :

```
<script src="http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip" type="application/javascript">
</script>
```

Anybody knows why the parent.document.write function is working (it puts the code into the head html section) but not loads the ip ?!

Ok guys we have an alternative which is working but still not answers the question which drives me mad, why is mine not working ?!

The workaround =

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.src = 'http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip';
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript"; //specify type so that the browser won't ignore it
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
```

head.appendChild(scriptElement);

Comment: You have a typo; `scr`instead of `src`. This means your resource is not being loaded in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.src = 'http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip';
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript"; //specify type so that the browser won't ignore it
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Comment: Ok, great this works ! But it's still driving me mad. Why is my function inserting the script but not executing.
Yours is inserting + working !

Comment: @dr3: browsers will ignore type that it does not understand. Using `application/javascript` may cause the script to be ignored in some older browsers (although it's inserted). This answer uses `text/javascript` instead.

Comment: Thank you.

So if I would change from application to text in my orignal code with parent.document.write it would work ?

Comment: @dr3: You could try it, it may work. I'm not sure if document.write triggers a DOM changed event so that the browser will act on it accordingly (like execute script tags).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create script element, load it and execute - try document.createElement instead:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.src = 'http://backlinker.nl/ip.php?callback=getip';
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Comment: And you can find description and explanation of such behavior of document.write here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: Thank you but I tried it and it does not do anything. It does not add a script tag to the html code.

Comment: I tried to adjust to </sc'+'ript> but still does not work. its driving me crazy.

Comment: I've made test of "document.createElement" approach - all works fine. parent.document.write and document.write gives no results. Try to put alert("") to your js to determine is really problem is with loading and executing js code

Comment: Thanks, will try in a minute !