# html5 Boiler Plate: <\/script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a neat little snippet of code that makes sure jQuery is succesfully loaded from a CDN or it includes a local copy.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

#### I get the idea but why does the `script` tag have two `\/` like so: `<\/script>`?

Is there a special reason that makes that method perferable to the standard way to close the tag?

Comment: **This will give you insight** `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash before `/` ensures that `<\/script>` is not interpreted as a closing script tag for the outer script. Without the slash, it would be parsed as:

```
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
')</script> <!-- where's the starting <script> ? -->
```

The backslash is used to escape characters inside a string. `\/` is treated as `/`.

(see [WHATWG: 4.12.1.2 Restrictions for contents of script elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) for more information about this topic)

Answer (score 1):

It is a escape character so `\/` is equals to `/`

so final script appended to document if jQuery is not loaded:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```