# Loading script asynchronisoly within script tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, mime-types

My problem is maybe specific and not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write).

I'm trying to load a HTML file and a script from Copy (which is a Dropbox-like) but since Copy declares those files with mime-type `text/plain` with a header `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` I get the error within Chrome `strict MIME type checking is enabled`.

I decided to load the content within a script tag. This is my attempt:

```
z = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* this is for the script.js file which is actually
                            jquery.min.js with bootstrap.min.js */
z.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (z.readyState == 4) {
        if (z.status == 200) {
            x = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* this is for the HTML file */
            x.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (x.readyState == 4) {
                    if (x.status == 200) {
                        document.write(x.responseText.replace("\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"xfiles/sys/script.js\">\x3C/script>", "\x3Cscript type=\"text/javascript\">" + z.responseText + "\x3C/script>").replace("<head>", "<head><base href='http://copy.com/N9NLnrlQvzer/residanat/'/>"));
                    }
                }
            };
            x.open("GET", "http://copy.com/N9NLnrlQvzer/residanat/index.html", true);
            x.send(null);
        }
    }
};
z.open("GET", "http://copy.com/N9NLnrlQvzer/residanat/xfiles/sys/script.js", true);
z.send(null);
```

The content is actually loading but I get a funny result.

Any clues about what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "funny result"? Was that the best description you could come up with !

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not find any that matchs what I got. Could you please check it and describe what you found?

Comment: Describe us what output do you see. Check for JS errors in the console. What is the response received?

Comment: The `script.js` file is loaded then the `index.html` file then modification of the script tag is done as expected with content of the `script.js` instead of the `src` attribute but the body content is filled with script (from the `script.js` file). I really don't know how to desribe what happened! Check it and you'll see..

Comment: @adeneo How could I be more specific? Have you got a clue?! I bet you found it funny too.. ^^