# Writing HTML-String to new window from Javascript in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

How can I write a HTML-conform String to a new window using a JSP with inner Javascript?

Our Situation: 
- Theres a .jsp-File used by a Tomcat-Server 
- The .jsp contains a `<script language="Javascript>`-Tag
- this script needs to write a complete, HTML-5-valid-String to a new Window using `window.open` and `'window'.document.write(htmlString)`

Our .jsp-File (schematic): 
    `<%@ include file = "..." %>
     <...some page imports...>
     <...some scripts...> 
                   (e.g. <script type = "text/javascript" src="...."> </script>)
     <% 
     String strMethod = "foo_Method_Bar";
     String strOutput = "";
     strOutput = someJavaBean-Call_that_brings_valid_html5_string_with_script-Nodes;
     %>
    ...
     <script language="Javascript">
     var strHTML = "<%=strOutput%>";
     var win = window.open('','','width=...,height=...');
     win.document.write(strHTML);
     top.close();
     win.focus();
     </script>`

Our Problem (schematic): 
- .jsp-File gets called. 
- .jsp-File calls a JavaBean and sets a global String-Variable to the HTML-String (including  `<script>`-Tags, DocType-Declarations, etc.) 
- .jsp-File replaces all occurrences of the Variable with the obtained String 
- javascript (`<script>`-Tag in the .jsp-File) gets Executed 
- `<script>`-Tag of Javascript is already closed, before 'window'.document.write(strHTML) gets executed, because theres a `</script>`-Tag in the Javascript
e.g. 
    `<script language="Javascript">
    var strHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> ... <script> ... </script> ... </html>;
    var win = window.open(...);
    win.document.write(strHTML);
    </script>`

- I've searched for quite some time now and I don't have a clue how to solve this issue. 
- Writing the HTML-Sourcecode into the Server-File-System and accessing it later on or something like that would be really, really dirty. 
- Part of the Problem is that we (of course) have to use this type of javascript-call in the .jsp-File for historical reasons...;-) 
- Is there maybe a way to assign the strHTML-Variable in the .jsp-File by Reference only (e.g. without replacing the <%=strOutput%>-Variable)?

Additional Info: 
The HTML-String-Generation is used at various places of our programs, multiple times, so i hoped not to have to escape any special CharacterSequences for this particular Call to work.

Appreciate all your help and ideas on this...;-)

**Solved:
See also [Why split the  tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write) on this issue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MUST escape the closing script in the string `<\/script>` unless the document.write lives in an external .script

Also remember to close the document, and no spaces in the parameters to window.open

like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var strHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> ... <script> ... <\/script> ... </html>';
  var win = window.open("","winname","resizable,scrollbars");
  win.document.write(strHTML);
  win.document.close();
</script>
```

Comment: The Suggestion seems legit, I've added some additional Info to the Question ... ;-) Thanks anyway, I'll keep it as possible workaround at the back of my mind...xD

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you need to document.write a script tag, you need to escape the end script tag unless the document.write lives in an external .js file. End of issue.

Comment: You're right, found some explanation on this here:
[Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)