# How to get Jackson to escape a </script> in output string?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jackson

I have a simple Java object that I'm using Jackson to serialize to JSON, and then I'm dropping that into a `<script>` tag in my JSP page as part of initializing a JavaScript object.  e.g.

```
<script>SomeLib.load(${someObject});</script>
```

This works great *unless* one of the fields of someObject is a String that contains `"</script>"`, because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write).  That is, if the output looks like this:

```
<script>SomeLib.load({"someValue":"hacked!</script>"});</script>
```

then the browser (tested in both Chrome and FF so far) believes the `</script>` tag after `hacked!` is closing the script tag.  Which breaks the JavaScript and leaves `"});</script>` visible to the user.

Is there a way to get Jackson to escape that value in some fashion that will fix this problem?

Comment: Just escape the xml, you'd need a library for that unless you can use jstl, but since it looks like you are using a sort of tag library, just use the jstl function library's escapexml, OR the core jstl's library "out" which escapes xml by default

Comment: @zack6849 that's not quite right because `escapeXml="true"` will also escape the quotes, you end up with `{&#034;someValue&#034;:&#034;hacked!</script>&#034;}`

Comment: Escaping the forward slash `/` is common pattern I often see to counter this kind of "attack" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288322/how-to-get-jackson-to-escape-a-script-in-output-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ravis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378980/822870) is wrong. See my comment there.

A better way is to escape the slash in `</` with a backslash, like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<script>SomeLib.load(${fn:replace(jsonString, "</", "<\\/")});</script>
```

Note: two backslashes are needed so the first one is escaped in the JSP syntax.

The good part is, it needs no special decoding.

PS: To do it on Jackson side, see [this blog](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/08/entry_476.html) - it covers escaping other characters, but just add slash to the list to escape (all) slash characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSTL function `fn:replace()` to escape just the starting `<` with `&lt;` which would effectively prevent any tag in your JSON **string** from getting interpreted as HTML.

So, this

```
<script>SomeLib.load(${fn:replace(jsonString, "<", "&lt;")});</script>
```

would get rendered fine in a browser as

```
<script>SomeLib.load({"someValue":"hacked!&lt;/script>"});</script>
```

But, before you can use `replace()` you'll need to import the JSTL *functions* tag library as

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

---

> No, that won't work because the < will literally be in that JavaScript string (it is not unescaped).

That's the whole point because if it comes out as `<`, it would break the HTML parser/browser.

You need to remember that when a protocol or application encodes something (like a URL string encoded in UTF-8 by a browser) it needs to be decoded as well prior to being used (like the web server does with the URL at server-side) or the functionality could break.

So, now that you know that your JSON string comes semi-encoded, you would need to modify the consumer as well; either the `SomeLib.load()` method to replace `&lt;` back with a `<`, or if that's a third-party library, decode its input in Javascript itself.

```
<script>
  var json = '${fn:replace(jsonString, "<", "&lt;")}';
  SomeLib.load(JSON.parse(json.replace("&lt;", "<")));
</script>
```

Comment: No, that won't work because the &lt; will literally be in that JavaScript string (it is not unescaped). http://jsbin.com/kemeqagare

Comment: This is wrong. If the original data contains "&lt;" then your code will mangle it to "<".